# Whatever happened to the 'entry' keyword?

Tags: c, language-design

While cruising through my white book the other day, I noticed in the list of C keywords.
**entry** is one of the keywords on that list.

It is reserved for future use.  Thinking back to my Fortran days, there was a function of some sort that used an **entry** statement to make a second argument signature, or entry point into a function.

Is this what **entry** was originally intended to be used for? or something completely different?

What is the story on the **entry** keyword?

Comment: @Evil, every time I see your image, it reminds me of a "Thomas the Tank Engine" gone horribly wrong :-). I'm tempted to show it to my 4yo son to see what name it should get from the Thomas stable.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I appreciate your four-year old would now be 19; but what name did they give Tom Gone Wrong?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had no idea, so I googled to find something about this. This is what I found.

First, it was included as a reserved keyword.

> **Q**: What was the entry keyword mentioned in K&R1?
>   **A**: It was reserved to allow functions with multiple, differently-named entry points, but it has been withdrawn.

(From http://archives.devshed.com/forums/c-c-134/c-programming-faqs-371017.html.)

It was never standardized; some compilers used it, [in a very personal way](http://bytes.com/forum/thread214853.html).

It was later declared obsolete, I guess.

Answer (score 18):

In FORTRAN, "ENTRY" could declare a second entry point into a subroutine.  It was a structured programming nightmare, and fortunately C decided not to adopt it.

Comment: Was it part of the original K&R standard? Could you show an example code?

Comment: @Gábor it was marked as a reserved keyword in K&R1, but as far as I know, (almost) nobody implemented it.

Answer (score 12):

The entry keyword came from [PL/I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I) and allowed multiple entry points into a function.  The keyword was implemented by some compilers but was never standardized.

Comment: +1 for an interesting history. I can just see the fits the structured programming fans would be having if, in addition to allowing multiple returns, C also allowed multiple calls to different places within a function. It's almost worth doing to see how they'd react :-).

Comment: That would truly cement C's position as "all the power and speed of assembly language, with all the readability of assembly language".

Answer (score 4):

To complement the accepted answer 'entry' is mentioned in K&R1:

> **2.3 Keywords**
>
> The following identifiers are reserved for use as keywords, and may not be used otherwise
>
> int extern else
>
> char register for
>
> float typedef do
>
> double static while
>
> struct goto switch
>
> union return case
>
> long sizeof default
>
> short break entry
>
> unsigned continue
>
> auto if

and here:

> The entry keyword is not currently implemented by any compiler but is
> reserved for future use. Some implementations also reserve the words 'fortran'
> and 'asm'.

Then in the Rationale for the ANSI C language (C89) it is mentioned here:

> **3.1.1 Keyword**
>
> [...]
>
> The keywords `entry`, `fortran`, and `asm` have not been included since they were either never used, or are not portable. Uses of `fortran` and `asm` as keywords are noted as *common extensions*.