# can any one tell me stream is a reserved keyword in c or c++;

Tags: c++, c

I am using a function pointer variable named as "stream. SO i think it might create errors if it is a reserved keyword in c or c++.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to try yourself?

Comment: I am sure the compiler will tell you this quite happily.

Comment: http://cs.smu.ca/~porter/csc/ref/cpp_keywords.html

Comment: You're absolutely correct - it _will_ create an error if it is a reserved word :-)

Comment: Wrong guys. Assuming a compiler will tell you gets people into trouble every day.

Comment: -1. how hard is it to google for "reserved keyword c c++"?

Comment: A PDF of the C Standard (a draft of it) is [freely available online](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

No, `stream` is not a keyword in either C or C++. See the accepted answer to [Why is "array" marked as a reserved word in Visual-C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372580/why-is-array-a-reserved-word-in-c-c)

However, as pointed out by @pmg, this is not the whole story. Identifiers starting with `str` followed by a lowercase letter are reserved by the C standard for additional string functions. The `gcc` manual provides a [handy list of identifiers to be avoided](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Reserved-Names.html).

Comment: Yes, balu, we are sure.

Comment: -1 `array` and `stream` are different: the first is available for any use; the 2nd is reserved by the C Standard.

Comment: -1 revoked after the edit -- in fact changed to a +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

As other answers say stream is not a keyword.

However it IS technically a reserved identifier - all identifiers starting with str followed by a lower case letter are reserved for future additions to string.h

So in theory there's a possibility that a future version of C could introduce a standard function called stream and thus break your code.  However the actual chance of that happening is probably tiny.

Comment: +1 The only correct answer so far: `printf` also is not a keyword and you really shouldn't use it for your own identifiers.