# Is "array" a keyword under c++11 standards?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

While using "array" as an identifier Codeblocks highlighted it like the other keywords. 
I searched it up in 
[Why is "array" marked as a reserved word in Visual-C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372580/why-is-array-a-reserved-word-in-c-c?answertab=votes#tab-top)

But the answers were outdated. If yes, how is it used ?

Comment: No, it isn't. There's a plain table of keywords in the standard: http://i.imgur.com/N5RfKh2.png. By the way, you can change which words C::B highlights in the settings.

Comment: No, see e.g. [this up to date reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). However, since the C++11 standard it is a [standard container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: That's because "array" is in your editor's list of keywords, either because someone thought it was a good idea to colour it like one, or because the list is shared with a language where "array" *is* a keyword. You can probably edit that list if you want a standards-compliant one.

Comment: CodeBlocks would probably also highlight a variable called `string` - usually syntax highlighters look for specific words and don't care about the context so there is no way for the syntax highlighter to know if you had earlier `#include<array>` and `using namespace std;` or not and so it is being cautious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, array is not a keyword.

Still, there is a C++11 standard-library type: [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), a fixed-length array container.

Here a list of the keywords from the C++1y draft:

```
alignas    continue     friend    register         true
alignof    decltype     goto      reinterpret_cast try
asm        default      if        return           typedef
auto       delete       inline    short            typeid
bool       do           int       signed           typename
break      double       long      sizeof           union
case       dynamic_cast mutable   static           unsigned
catch      else         namespace static_assert    using
char       enum         new       static_cast      virtual
char16_t   explicit     noexcept  struct           void
char32_t   export       nullptr   switch           volatile
class      extern       operator  template         wchar_t
const      false        private   this             while
constexpr  float        protected thread_local
const_cast for          public    throw
```

These alternative representations (whose very existence I dislike, but that's just me) are not keywords though still reserved:

```
and    and_eq bitand bitor compl  not
not_eq or     or_eq  xor   xor_eq
```

Contextual keywords (override control, put at the end of the function declaration in a class (`new` not listed because already a keyword))

```
final   override
```

Comment: what about `size_t`? I find that code using `size_t` (instead of the correct `std::size_t`) tends to compile ...

Comment: @Walter: Any standard header may include any other, as the creator saw fit, and the C inherited and derived headers can contain `::size_t`, which in that case must be equal to `std::size_t` and `decltype(sizeof 0)`.

Comment: Is such a header still standard compliant? It pollutes the global namespace which I thought shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 4):

`array` is not a keyword, but the C++11 standard defines its STL with a [`std::array`  template container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).  You should prefer

```
 std::array<int,5> tab;
```

instead of `int tab[5];` because `std::array` have interesting functions and works better with other parts of the STL library.

Since it is a standard container, I would advise you to avoid using the `array` (or `vector`, because of `std::vector`, etc...) identifier in your own code (especially in reusable headers), to avoid future potential conflicts with `<array>` header, and also for readability reasons. But in principle you could define your own `array` but I don't recommend that.

Answer (score 3):

`array` is a standard container, as you can see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/).

It doesn't belong to the keywords, but it's part of the standard library.

Answer (score 3):

C++ Keywords are listed in the **C++ standard, section § 2.13**.

`array` is not listed there, so it isn't.

---

**Note:**

- [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is a standard type, but not a keyword.
- `array` is a valid identifier, but it certainly is discouraged because of the previous point.