# What are the new reserved words in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, porting, c++03, reserved-words

In preparing our source code to eventually move up to C++11 from C++03, I'd like to rename any tokens that inadvertently collide with new reserved words in C++11 that were not present in C++03.

I know there is the new reserved word `final` in C++11, are there other new reserved words that I should look for in our C++03 code base and rename?

Other than reserved words, are there any other changes that are made in C++11 wherein valid C++03 code is no longer valid in C++11?

While I'm at it, are there any changes that might be required for C++14?

Comment: `final` is not reserved; it is only a keyword in a certain position, where the token `final` wasn't legal prior to C++11.  It is probably a good idea to avoid it anyhow (as primitive syntax highlighting will get confusing, among other things), but it will not break your code base.  What, exactly, are you concerned about?

Comment: Note [final and override are identifiers with special meaning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30404388/1708801).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: there is a full list in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25326530/2564301. Apart from that, it ought to be quite trivial to find using any search engine ...

Comment: @Jongware sure, but if this was asked before it then this should be closed as duplicate of that and not the one above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
alignas
alignof
char16_t
char32_t
constexpr
decltype
default
export
noexcept
nullptr
static_assert
thread_local
using
```

`override` and `final` are reserved only in certain contexts.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword