# C++ can't use std::array, due to cli::array keyword Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-cli, stdarray

I want to declare a `std::array`, but the array part gets recognized as `cli::array` keyword (see [Why is "array" marked as a reserved word in Visual-C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372580/why-is-array-marked-as-a-reserved-word-in-visual-c)), which means that the `std::` doesnt affect it. How can a stop *Visual Studio* from automatically `using namespace cli`, or specify that I want to use `std::array`?

[image: the blue array-word recognized as keyword]

The blue array-word recognized as keyword

Comment: Did you mean `std::array<char, N>` (for some `N` like `std::array<char, 5>`)?

Comment: Just to be clear: This is about the misinterpretation of the IDE, not the compilation, right? It still compiles as expected (if you fix the template arguments), doesn't it?

Comment: It is just a syntax coloring glitch, it does not stop you from using std::array.  If you want to write your code like this, not specifying the array size, then you meant to use std::vector instead.

Comment: If you don’t want the cli namespace, don’t make a cli project

Comment: @Artyer, jup that was it, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::array` accepts [two template arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). One is the type of the elements and the other accepts the number of elements.

If you mean to use a dynamic array, then use `std::vector`.