# What does the unary plus operator do?

Tags: c#, c++, c, unary-operator

What does the unary plus operator do? There are several definitions that I have found ([here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130511040723/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691365(VS.71).aspx) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160222192353/http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson02.aspx)) but I still have no idea what it would be used for. It seems like it doesn't do anything but there has be a reason for it, right?

Comment: I think the [historical reason](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7611586/2932052) is severely underestimated.

Comment: A question with three different language tags is quite ambiguous/bad! The answers are very different for C# (overloadable) and C (no overloading) and C++ (overloadable but inherits this from C and hence its properties too).

Comment: I'd like to add a link to Eric Lippert's top 10 flaws of C#. You will find the unary plus operator in the honorable mentions: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2425867 He basically says it should be removed or it should have never been added.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's there to be overloaded if you feel the need; for all predefined types it's essentially a no-op.

The practical uses of a no-op unary arithmetic operator are pretty limited, and tend to relate to the consequences of using a value in an arithmetic expression, rather than the operator itself.  For example, it can be used to force widening from smaller integral types to `int`, or ensure that an expression's result is treated as an rvalue and therefore not compatible with a non-`const` reference parameter.  I submit, however, that these uses are better suited to code golf than readability. :-)

Comment: This isn't actually true, as several examples below indicate.

Comment: Okay, I'll buy that it has some uses, but most of the uses discussed below relate to the fact that it's a numeric expression built using a no-op operator: for example, promoting to `int` and resulting in an rvalue are effects of expression-ness, not of the + operator itself.

Answer (score 134):

Actually, unary plus *does* do something - even in C.  It performs the *[usual arithmetic conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t4w2bkb%28VS.80%29.aspx)* on the operand and returns a new value, which can be an integer of greater width.  If the original value was an unsigned integer of lesser width than `int`, it will be changed to a `signed` value as well.

Usually this isn't that important, but it *can* have an effect, so it's *not* a good idea to use unary plus as a sort of "comment" denoting that an integer is positive.  Consider the following C++ program:

```
void foo(unsigned short x)
{
 std::cout << "x is an unsigned short" << std::endl;
}

void foo(int x)
{
 std::cout << "x is an int" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
 unsigned short x = 5;
 foo(+x);
}
```

This will display "x is an int".

So in this example unary plus created a new value with a different type *and* signedness.

Comment: if you're writing code that produces given result when given a short and an int that compares equal, then you probably have a different problem

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear (sidenote: In C, I couldn't get the example to work, since I can't overload the foo function)

Comment: what does it mean by saying `an integer of greater width`?

Comment: in this context, "width" refers to the number of bytes of storage associated with the value.

Answer (score 45):

From K&R second edition:

> The unary + is new with the ANSI standard. It was added for symmetry with the unary -.

Comment: Absolutely. ***This is the historical reason.** C++ had to adapt it, so it had to deal with overloading.

Answer (score 39):

I've seen it used for clarity, to emphasize the positive value as distinct from a negative value:

```
shift(+1);
shift(-1);
```

But that's a pretty weak use. The answer is definitely overloading.

Comment: I've done this too, especially when dealing with vectors like `vec3(+1,-1,-1)`

Answer (score 30):

One thing the built-in unary `+` does is turning lvalue into an rvalue. For example, you can do this

```
int x;
&x;
```

but you can't do this

```
&+x;
```

:)

P.S. "Overloading" is definitely not the right answer. Unary `+` was inherited from C and there's no user-level operator overloading in C.

Answer (score 15):

The main thing unary + accomplishes is type promotion to an int for smaller-than-int data types. This can be quite useful if you're trying to print char data using `std::cout` as numeric data.

```
char x = 5;
std::cout << +x << "\n";
```

is very different from

```
char x=5;
std::cout << x << "\n";
```

It's also available for overloading, but in practice your overload *should* be nearly a NOP.

Answer (score 13):

If you ever need to print the numeric value of raw bytes (eg, small numbers stored as char) for debug or whatever reason, unary + can simplify the print code. Consider

```
char c = 42;
cout << c << endl;           // prints "*\n", not what you want in this case
cout << (int)c << endl;      // prints "42\n", ok
cout << +c << endl;          // prints "42\n", much easier to type
```

This is just a quick example. I am sure there are other times when unary + can help treat your bytes more like numbers instead of like text.

Answer (score 4):

A historical tidbit. The C99 standardization committee also thought existing uses of unary plus were fairly rare, as evidenced by their considering reusing it to achieve another feature in the language: inhibition of translation-time evaluation of floating-point constant expressions. See the following quote from the C Rationale, section F.7.4:

> An early version of this specification allowed translation-time constant arithmetic, but
>   empowered the unary + operator, when applied to an operand, to inhibit translation-time
>   evaluation of constant expressions.

In the end, the semantics were reversed, with run-time evaluation enforced in most contexts (at least up to the "as if" rule), and the ability to enforce translation-time evaluation by the use of static initializers. Note that the main difference lies in the occurrence of floating point exceptions, and other floating point rounding or precision settings, where present.

Answer (score 3):

Not much. The general argument for allowing the overload of `operator+()` is that there are definitely real world uses for overloading `operator-()`, and it would be *very* weird (or asymmetrical) if you were to allow overloading `operator-()` but not `operator+()`.

*I believe that I first read this argument from Stroustrop, but I don't have my books with me right to verify it. I might be wrong.*

Answer (score 3):

Unary plus was present in C, where it did absolutely nothing (much like the `auto` keyword).  In order to not have it, Stroustrup would have had to introduce a gratuitous incompatibility with C.

Once it was in C++, it was natural to allow an overload function, just like unary minus, and Stroustrup might have introduced it for that reason if it wasn't already there.

So, it means nothing.  It can be used as as sort of decoration to make things look more symmetrical, using +1.5 as the opposite to -1.5 for example.  In C++, it can be overloaded, but it's going to be confusing if `operator+()` does anything.  Remember the standard rule:  when overloading arithmetic operators, do things like the `int`s do.

If you're looking for a reason why it's there, find something about the early history of C.  I suspect there was no good reason, as C was not really designed.  Consider the useless `auto` keyword (presumably in contrast to `static`, now being recycled in C++0x), and the `entry` keyword, which never did anything (and later omitted in C90).  There's a famous email in which Ritchie or Kernighan say that, when they realized the operator precedence had problems, there were already three installations with thousands of lines of code that they didn't want to break.

Comment: The only non-arithmetic overload that I've seen that makes sense was in regular expressions or grammars where (+term) means one or more tems. (Which is fairly standard regular expression syntax)

Comment: About `entry`: (http://stackoverflow.com/q/254395/153285). These days, if you want multiple entry points, just use tail calls and profile-guided optimization.

Comment: I believe that even in C99, given `extern volatile int foo;`, a compiler given the statement `+foo;` would be required to perform a read of the indicated address on any platform where any means might conceivably exist to determine that the read took place.  I'm not sure that would be required if the statement were just "foo", though many compilers will do it as a courtesy.

Answer (score 2):

I can't cite any source for this, but I have come to understand it is for explicit type promotion, which implies lossless type conversion.  That puts it at the top of the conversion hierarchy,

- **Promotion:** `new_type operator+(old_type)`
- **Conversion:** `new_type(old_type)`
- **Cast:** `operator(new_type)(old_type)`
- **Coercion:** `new_type operator=(old_type)`

Of course, that's from my interpretation of a note in one of the microsoft (really old) c/c++ manuals that I read about 15 years ago, so take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned short x = 5;
    printf ("%d\n",sizeof(+x)); 
    printf ("%d\n",sizeof(x)); 
    return 0;
}
```

As shown in the example above, the unary + really changes the type, size 4 and 2 respectively. Weird that the expression +x is indeed calculated in the sizeof, I thought that was not supposed to. Perhaps it's due to the fact that sizeof has the same priority as the unary +.

Comment: for the record, `sizeof +x` does *not* actually evaluate the expression `+x`, it just determines the type of the expression at compile-time and returns the size of that type. you can see this in practice by writing `sizeof ++x`, which will not increment the value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting usage I haven't seen mentioned here for C++ is that it allows non-capturing lambdas to be converted to function pointers:

```cpp
void (*func_ptr)();
func_ptr = +[](){};

int (*func_ptr2)(int, int);
func_ptr2 = +[](int x, int y){return x + y;};
```

The `+` operator forces the non-capturing lambda to be converted to a function pointer via its implicit user-declared conversion function.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** Rewrote completely, because I was waaaayyy off in my original answer.

This should allow you to handle the explicit declaration of your type as a positive value (I think in mostly non-mathematical operations).  It seems that negation would be more useful, but I guess here's an example of where it might make a difference:

```
public struct Acceleration
{
    private readonly decimal rate;
    private readonly Vector vector;

    public Acceleration(decimal rate, Vector vector)
    {
        this.vector = vector;
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public static Acceleration operator +(Acceleration other)
    {
        if (other.Vector.Z >= 0)
        {
            return other;
        }
        return new Acceleration(other.Rate, new Vector(other.vector.X, other.Vector.Y, -other.vector.Z));
    }

    public static Acceleration operator -(Acceleration other)
    {
        if (other.Vector.Z <= 0)
        {
            return other;
        }
        return new Acceleration(other.Rate, new Vector(other.vector.X, other.Vector.Y, -other.vector.Z));
    }

    public decimal Rate
    {
        get { return rate; }
    }

    public Vector Vector
    {
        get { return vector; }
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a unary operation to me. It takes two arguments (april and may) so that'd be binary.

Comment: That's binary plus.  Unary plus is just "+1" or some such, with no left operand.

Comment: my bad.  forgot my CS101.  fixed.

Comment: If I found that kind of overload in production code, I would definitely mark it as a bug and fix it as soon as possible. The semantics of `+` is not to make a value positive, but to leave its sign unchanged.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you could use it to always make a number positive. Just overload the unary + operator to be abs. Not really worth confusing your fellow developers, unless you really just want to obfuscate your code. Then it'd work nicely.

Comment: That would make it not the opposite of unary minus which would be confusing, unless you also overload unary minus to be the negative abs, which would make all kinds of math things wierd

Comment: Uhh, yeah. That's why I suggested not doing it.

Comment: @Davy8: What makes you think unary plus is *currently* the "opposite" of unary minus? What is the "opposite" of the bitwise complement operator `~`? I'm not sure what your definition of "opposite" is, but I suspect it's biased by experience of what unary plus and unary minus currently do.

Answer (score -2):

simply that used to convince which numbers are positive

eg;

```
int a=10;
System.out.println(+x);// prints 10(that means,that number 10 multiply by +1,{10*+1})

//if we use unary minus

int a=10;
System.out.println(-x);//prints -10(that means,that number 10 multiply by +1,{10*-1})
```