# Why is var m = 6 + + + + + + + + 6; valid in c#?

Tags: c#

Title is most of the question, what allows this to be valid code? Is there any benefit or trick that would allow me to utilize this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [unary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691364(VS.71).aspx) plus operator has higher [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(VS.71).aspx) than the [addition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691371(VS.71).aspx) operator, just split your expression into multiple grouped expressions and it will seem pretty obvious:

```
var m = 6 + ( +( +( +( +( +( +( +( 6 ))))))));
      //6 + 6
```

Answer (score 3):

The extra pluses are being treated as positive indicators.  As in `+1`.

Comment: What was the rational on adding positive indicators?? Anyone have any insight to this?

Comment: so it's 6 + really really very positive 6?

Comment: @Dested: Rationale?  Rationale?  The inmates run that asylum, my friend.  If anything, it would be symmetry.

Comment: @Mike Two: Yes.  As positive as you can get without adding another plus sign.

Comment: can you do the same thing with minus ( 6 - - - - - - 6) ?

Comment: @Thilo: Apparently... but with a less stable effect, obviously.

Comment: @Dested: Some ideas on rationale here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727516/what-does-the-unary-plus-operator-do