# One plus plus two compiles unexpectedly

Tags: java, operators

So, I expect this not to compile, and it doesn't:

```
// the two is inc'd, so reduces symbolically to println(int int)
// which is a compile error
System.out.println(1 ++ 2);
```

But this does:

```
System.out.println(1 + + 2);   // returns three
```

What gives? Shouldn't it also not compile?

Also, this question is very hard to search for because of the operators..

Comment: ++ is an increment operator so the compiler may be expecting a variable name either before or after ++

Comment: In the second case `+` is a "syntactic sugar" operator (mirroring `-`) that does nothing to the operand.

Comment: *"Also, this question is very hard to search for because of the operators.."* Why not search for 'Java operators'? You will get a list of operators and these operators are listed.

Comment: @Radiodef so once you search for "java operators" and you get hundreds of unrelated questions with the dozens of operator combinations Java uses, is there a way to further refine the search?

Comment: To search for symbols, use http://symbolhound.com/ (not sure it would solve this problem, but it's a useful resource)

Comment: [Analogous question in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24279192/1157100) and [C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2528543/1157100). You can go even further, with `1 + + + + + 2`, in C [as in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/470139/1157100).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Java is interpreting the working `1 + + 2` as 1 plus positive 2.  See the [Unary operator section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

Comment: Though not as detailed as the other correct answers, this one was fairly quick to parse through and understand.

Comment: Sometimes a detailed breakdown of the specification is not needed. Sometimes, the best answer is the simplest one. :)

Answer (score 41):

From the Specification, on [Lexical Translations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2)

> **The longest possible translation is used at each step, even if the
>   result does not ultimately make a correct program while another
>   lexical translation would.** There is one exception: if lexical
>   translation occurs in a type context (§4.11) and the input stream has
>   two or more consecutive > characters that are followed by a non->
>   character, then each > character must be translated to the token for
>   the numerical comparison operator >.

(Also known as [maximal munch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch).)

The `++` is interpreted as a [postfix increment operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2) which cannot be applied to an integer literal, thus the compiler error.

While

```
1 + + 2
```

each character is interpreted separately. `1` is an integer literal, `+` is the [additive operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2), `+` is the [unary plus operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3), and `2` is an integer literal. The whole expression is equivalent to

```
1 + (+2)
```

which is easier to read.

Answer (score 6):

In Java/C++/C `++` is not same as `+ +`. `++`/`--` are the [Increment/Decrement operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators).
The first case does not work because it does not apply to literals (`1` or `2`). 
Even then it would not be a valid statement, Neither `1++ 2` nor `1 ++2` are valid statement in Java. The second example works because it is interpreted as `1 + (+2)`. The Java lexer ignores white space. ​In the same way this is valid :

```
1 + + + 2   --> 1 + (+ (+2))
```

Or

```
1 + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + 2
```

​It works only because `+` is a `unary` operator. It does not work for strings as below :

```
"a" + + "b"   // does not work because +"b" is not valid.
```

Similarly it is not valid with multiplication

```
1 * * 2       // does not work because *2 is not valid.
```

Comment: It isn't quite right to say the lexer ignores whitespace, eh? After all, it doesnt interpret `1++2` as `int biplus unplus int`, nor `1+ +2` as `int incr int`

Answer (score 3):

The message is:

```
Main.java:14: error: ')' expected
        System.out.println(1 ++ 2);
                               ^
```

The `1 ++ 2` statement is parsed as `1` followed by `++` followed by `2`. This is interpreted as `1++` and `2` creating a syntax error (and not an `unexpected type` error; in fact, you will get the same error if you used variables e.g. `i ++ j`).

---

The `1 + + 2` statement on the other hand is parsed as `1` followed by `+` followed by `+2` which compiles as expected. The space between the two operators separates the two operators.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's easier to see a problem using variables.

Your snippet could be rewritten as:

```
int a = 1;
int b = +2;
System.out.println(a + b);
```

Now, you can easily see that the second `+` operator is used to indicate a positive value.
You could also have written `+1 + +2`.

The `-` operator could be used to negate an expression.

`+` and `-` are unary operators.