# What is the purpose of Java's unary plus operator?

Tags: java, language-history, unary-operator

Java's unary plus operator appears to have come over from C, via C++.

```
int result = +1;
```

It appears to have the following effects:

- Unboxes its operand, if it's a wrapper object
- Promotes its operand to `int`, if it's not already an `int` or wider
- Complicates slightly the parsing of evil expressions containing large numbers of consecutive plus signs

It seems to me that there are better/clearer ways to do all of these things.

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727516/what-does-the-unary-plus-operator-do), concerning the counterpart operator in C#, someone said that "It's there to be overloaded if you feel the need."

However, in Java, one cannot overload *any* operator. So does this unary plus operator exist in Java only because it existed in C++?

Comment: Code obfuscation contests... the SCJP exam...

Comment: Similar question for C, which does not have overload either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637005/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-unary-operator-in-c , and analogously to Java does type promotion.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The unary plus operator performs an automatic conversion to `int` when the type of its operand is `byte`, `char`, or `short`. This is called *unary numeric promotion*, and it enables you to do things like the following:

```
char c = 'c';
int i = +c;
```

Granted, it's of limited use. But it does have a purpose. See the specification, specifically sections **[§15.15.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3)** and **[§5.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#d5e7848)**.

Comment: Right, but it's redundant in that case. Since that's a widening conversion, `int i = c;` will do the same thing.

Comment: It's not necessarily redundant in a holistic sense, because it conveys intention. One might legitimately wonder of `int i = c`, "did the author of this code mean to assign `c` to an `int`?" Are there other ways to do it? Sure, but this is the shortest way that also conveys intention.

Comment: Good point. I think in practice I'd be more likely to do `int i = (int) c;` if I wanted to convey intention, but using the `+` is certainly shorter.

Comment: @JohnFeminella "conveys intention"? I don't really buy that since others reading the code wouldn't really know why it's there. As you can see from the other answers, it seems most people have no idea about _unary numeric promotion_. Personally, I always thought it was a no-op and it is there for purely cosmetic reasons. If numeric promotion is your intent, then `(int) c` is much clearer since it is a ubiquitous, widely accepted pattern. Still, +1 for teaching me something I didn't know.

Comment: I agree that `(int) c` is clearer. But I didn't say this was the _clearest_ way to do the conversion and also convey intention; I said it was the _shortest_. :)

Comment: but does `int a = -1; b = +a` result in `b = 1`?

Comment: @CpILL No, it doesn't.

Comment: I use unary + to enable vertical coherence in complex expressions.

Comment: The clearest way is without a cast as it is the simplest case of numeric promotion.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a short demonstration of what the unary plus will do to a `Character` variable:

```
private static void method(int i){
    System.out.println("int: " + i);
}

private static void method(char c){
    System.out.println("char: " + c);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Character ch = 'X';
    method(ch);
    method(+ch);        
}
```

The output of running this programme is:

```
char: X
int: 88
```

How it works: Unary + or - unbox their operand, if it's a wrapper object, then promote their operand to int, if not already an int or wider. So, as we can see, while the first call to `method` will choose the `char` overload (unboxing only), the second call will choose the `int` version of `method`. Variable `ch` of type `Character` will be passed into `method` as `int` argument because of the applied *unary plus*.

Comment: What exactly is a "programme"?

Answer (score 6):

I don't know, but I suspect it's there for symmetry with the (obviously necessary) unary minus operator.

Comment: It's entirely possible that if there weren't a unary plus operator in Java, I'd be sitting here on Stack Overflow complaining about it...

Comment: @Syntactic Unlikely. If there were no unary plus operator, you could use the `intValue()` method instead.

Answer (score 3):

One of Java's design goals was to be familiar (to a C/C++ developer), so when it came to operators like this I'm pretty sure they would have to have a strong reason to exclude it, not a good reason to need it.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is it's there because sometimes typing the plus out makes things clearer. You might want to emphasize the fact that some number is positive, as opposed to some negative number.

Also, to provide a real world example where it's used, positive temperatures tend to be always prefixed with a plus in some parts of the world.

Answer (score 2):

Many other languages have unary plus. It's customary to include it, and penny-pinching to exclude it. It's only a couple of lines in a compiler.

Answer (score -3):

The unary operators do the following for java:

- `+` Unary plus operator; indicates positive value (numbers are positive without this, however)
- `-` Unary minus operator; negates an expression
- `++` Increment operator; increments a value by 1
- `--` Decrement operator; decrements a value by 1
- `!` Logical complement operator; inverts the value of a boolean

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: The link you provided is misleading. Unary `+` does not "indicate a positive value": `+-1` equals `-1`.