# What is the purpose of the unary plus (+) operator in C?

Tags: c, expression, evaluation, unary-operator

In C, it's legal to write something like:

```
int foo = +4;
```

However, as far as I can tell, the unary plus (`+`) in `+4` is a no-op. Is it?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727516/what-does-the-unary-plus-operator-do

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s50et82s.aspx "The unary plus operator preceding an expression in parentheses forces the grouping of the enclosed operations. It is used with expressions involving more than one associative or commutative binary operator. The operand must have arithmetic type. The result is the value of the operand. An integral operand undergoes integral promotion. The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand."

Comment: K&R says it was just added for symmetry in the standard.

Comment: @Jeremy: there is. E.g. it says that `+short(1)` has type `int`, not `short`.

Comment: @Jeremy, re: Tim S. Check the source. Did you here the one about the airplane? :)

Comment: @TimS.: "*The unary plus operator preceding an expression in parentheses forces the grouping of the enclosed operations*" -- Oh? It's the parentheses, not the `+`, that forces the grouping.

Comment: @MSalters: `+short(1)` is a syntax error. Were you thinking of `+(short)1`?

Comment: Bjarne Stroustroup supplied an explanation in his calculator language in one of his books, paraphrased "when there's unary minus, someone always tries to do unary plus, so it's easier to just implement it than to explain why it's useless."

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As per the C90 standard in 6.3.3.3:

> The    result     of    the    unary     +   operator      is   the    **value     of    its   operand**.       The    integral      promotion       is 
>   performed      on   the   operand.     and   the   result    has  the   promoted      type.

and

> The    operand     of    the    unary     +   or    -    operator      shall     have    **arithmetic       type**..

Comment: So `+x` is a noop unless `sizeof x < sizeof(int)`?

Comment: These quotes from the standard show that the unary + is not simply a no-op. It does perform integral promotion on the operand. And, possibly more importantly, it does turn an lvalue into an rvalue.

Comment: Well, it's theoretically possible that `sizeof(short) == sizeof(int)` but a `short` has padding, and theoretically, on such a system the padding might need to be zeroed or sign extended.  Theoretically.

Comment: Note that when it says arithmetic type it refers to both Integral types and Floating types, the example Nemo shows works because pointers are outside this classification. Integral types and pointers form Scalar types.

Comment: This doesn't affect a `float` or a `double` at all, does it?

Comment: Why not just cast the value explicitly?

Answer (score 86):

You can use it as a sort of assertion that an expression has arithmetic type:

```
#define CHECK_ARITHMETIC(x) (+(x))
```

This will generate a compile-time error if `x` evaluates to (say) a pointer.

That is about the only practical use I can think of.

Comment: You can also cast an enum value to its integer value this way.

Comment: Just make sure to document that, because that is *completely* non-obvious

Comment: Why can't you do the same thing with, for example, `(-(-(x)))`?

Comment: @luxun, I'm fairly sure you can.

Comment: @GMan, isn't the enum to int conversion implicit in C?

Comment: @zneak: Yes, but with this you can do the conversion without having to specify the target type. There's no way to know, in general, the underlying type.

Comment: @luxun @zneak: Interesting idea...  Let me see...  OK, how about this.  If `int` is 32-bit and `x` happens to be an `int` equal to `-2^31`, then `-x` will overflow a signed integer which is technically Undefined Behavior.  :-)

Comment: @Nemo, the point being to trigger a compile-time error, as long as `CHECK_ARITHMETIC` isn't used in any assignment, I'm all right with that :)

Comment: @zneak: The point is to trigger a compile time error if the expression has pointer type, but to be a no-op if it has arithmetic type.  Your version does fine, except for arithmetic expressions that happen to evaluate to `INT_MIN`.  (Well, in theory, anyway.  In practice it probably works fine on any realistic machine.)  Still, a strict reading of the standard says these are different.

Comment: I meant that you can just do `CHECK_ARITHMETIC(x);` without using it in an assignment to get the compile error, and use `x` directly after that.

Comment: @zneak: Even if you do not use it in an assignment, merely to evaluate `-x` when `x` is `INT_MIN` is technically to invoke undefined behavior, I believe.

Comment: The same happens for `#define CHECK_ARITHMETIC(x) (-(x))`. Unary + was added to the ANSI standard only for symmetry with unary -.

Comment: @logic_max: The point of the suggestion is to use `(+(x))` to assert that an expression has arithmetic type at compile-time.  You _cannot_ use `(-(x))` or `(-(-(x)))` instead without risking undefined behavior.  Not that this is particularly useful...  And I am not claiming it was the rationale...  But it is the only way to do it to my knowledge.

Comment: @Nemo : Yes i get that,+1 for that. But, i don't think that (-(x)) will cause any undefined behavior. Both, unary + and - are not applicable on pointers, so both will generate compile time errors. The value at runtime has nothing to do with this.

Comment: You can use `-` just as well to assert arithmetic type as long as you don't **evaluate** the expression. For example, `(0&&-(x))`. If you want to ensure `x` is still evaluated, use `((x),(0&&-(x)))`.

Comment: @GManNickG There is absolutely no point in this, you can just cast it explicitly. Will be much more clear of what you want to do.

Answer (score 40):

There's one very handy use of the unary plus operator I know of: in macros. Suppose you want to do something like

```
#if FOO > 0
```

If `FOO` is undefined, the C language requires it be replaced by 0 in this case. But if `FOO` was defined with an empty definition, the above directive will result in an error. Instead you can use:

```
#if FOO+0 > 0
```

And now, the directive will be syntactically correct whether `FOO` is undefined, defined as blank, or defined as an integer value.

Of course whether this will yield the desired semantics is a completely separate question, but in some useful cases it will.

**Edit:** Note that you can even use this to **distinguish** the cases of `FOO` being defined as zero versus defined as blank, as in:

```
#if 2*FOO+1 == 1
/* FOO is 0 */
#else
/* FOO is blank */
#endif
```

Comment: By the way, I'd be interested in hearing if anyone has another way to do the tests I described. None have occurred to me...

Comment: Are you sure these preprocessor directives really relate to the unary + operator as seen in C? In you second example, with a blank `FOO`, the expression wouldn't be valid C.

Comment: zneak is right: this is a cool trick, but technically this is an example of the unary + operator being processed by the C preprocessor, not the C compiler.

Comment: `#ifndef FOO\n#define FOO 0\n#endif\n#if FOO > 0\n` woks.

Comment: @luxun: No, it doesn't. With `#define FOO`, `#ifndef FOO` is false. Undefined names are already replaced by 0 in `#if` so your code snippet is useless. Blank definitions are quite different from being undefined, and are common due to things like `-DFOO`.

Comment: Indeed it does. In any case, the pair of operators `- -` (space essential!) is equivalent to `+` as far as I can tell, making `+` rather redundant... Nope, that's wrong, it's not equivalent when the operand is `INT_MIN`... :-)

Comment: Won't (2*FOO+1) work as a legal runtime check on how FOO was defined as well?

Comment: As long as you place it inside `#ifdef FOO`, yes.

Comment: Sorry for bumping such an old answer, but isn't this an example of the binary plus rather than the unary plus?

Comment: @AuroraVollvik: It's unary plus if the macro happens to be defined but with empty definition.

Comment: This example is not a unary plus at all, this is a binary as mencioned by @AuroraVollvik. The `+` can be unary or binary operator, defined by use context, if you have two operands this is not a unary usage. Unary have only one operand.

Comment: @UndefinedBehavior: Whether it's unary or binary depends on how `FOO` is defined.

Comment: I don't think it's an operator when it's in a preprocessor macro.

Answer (score 19):

I found two things that unary `+` operator do is

- `integer promotion`
- `turning lvalue into rvalue`

**integer promotion example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char ch;
    short sh;
    int i;
    long l;

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",sizeof(ch),sizeof(sh),sizeof(i),sizeof(l));
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n",sizeof(+ch),sizeof(+sh),sizeof(+i),sizeof(+l));
    return 0;
}
```

Typical output (on 64-bit platform):

```
1 2 4 8
4 4 4 8
```

**turning lvalue into rvalue example:**

```
int i=0,j;

j=(+i)++; // error lvalue required
```

Comment: Finally. A potentially useful application that will inform some generic code of the size of an argument following integer promotion that may not be `sizeof(int)`. I've got no idea when I'll use it. But nice all the same. NB: edited answer to show that not everything goes to 4.

Answer (score 18):

Pretty much. It's mainly present for completeness, and to make constructions like this look a little cleaner:

```
int arr[] = {
    +4,
    -1,
    +1,
    -4,
};
```

Comment: No way this is cleaner than the alternative without the unary `+`s.

Answer (score 15):

#### Not precisely a no-op

The unary `+` operator does only one thing: *it applies the integer promotions*. Since those would occur anyway if the operand were used in an expression, one imagines that unary `+` is in C simply for symmetry with unary `-`.

It's difficult to see this in action because the promotions are so generally applied.

I came up with this:

```
printf("%zd\n", sizeof( (char) 'x'));
printf("%zd\n", sizeof(+(char) 'x'));
```

which (on my Mac) prints

```
1
4
```

Comment: This is useful for printing `char`s in C++ with `std::cout`.

Answer (score 14):

> What is the purpose of the unary '+' operator in C?

Unary plus was added to C for symmetry with unary minus, from the  [Rationale for International Standard—Programming Languages—C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf):

> Unary plus was adopted by the C89 Committee from several implementations, for symmetry with unary minus.

and it is not a no-op, it performs the integer promotions on its operand. Quoting from my answer to [Does Unary + operator do type conversions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24805580/1708801):

The draft C99 standard section `6.5.3.3` *Unary arithmetic operators* says:

> The result of the unary + operator is the value of its (promoted)
>   operand. **The integer promotions are performed on the operand**, and the
>   result has the promoted type.

Worth pointing out that [Annotated C++ Reference Manual(*ARM*)](http://www.stroustrup.com/arm.html) provides the following commentary on unary plus:

> Unary plus is a historical accident and generally useless.

Comment: In C++ it is also "abused" when a `static_cast` would show intent more clearly for example [Resolving ambiguous overload on function pointer and std::function for a lambda using +](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17822131/1708801)

Answer (score 1):

By 'no-op', do you mean the assembly instruction?
If so, then definitely not.

**+4 is just 4** - the compiler won't add any further instructions.

Comment: By 'noop', I meant 'doing nothing'–I expect compilers to not add an instruction for the sake of adding an instruction.

Comment: But `+(char)4` is not the same as `(char)4`.