# Unary + operator on an int&

Tags: c++, unary-operator

I have following statement and it compiles:

```
static unsigned char CMD[5] = {0x10,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06};

int Class::functionA(int *buflen)
{
    ...
    int length = sizeof(CMD); + *buflen; // compiler should cry! why not?
    ...
}
```

Why I get no compiler error?

Comment: What compiler? Do you compile with warnings on? When I compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` I get "warning: statement has no effect", and `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` gives "warning: expression result unused".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
+ *buflen;
```

Is a valid application of the unary `+` operator on an `int&`, it's basically a noop. It's the same as if you wrote this:

```
int i = 5;
+i; // noop
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6637005/500104) for what the unary `operator+` actually does to integers, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/727516/500104) what you can practically do with it.

Comment: "it's basically a noop" - in some implementations it's equivalent to `if (!buflen) kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV);` or what-have-you ;-). But that might depend entirely on optimization options, and I do agree that all being well it does nothing.

Comment: @Steve: Uh, yeah, assuming that `buflen` actually points to something valid. :)

Answer (score 4):

Because it isn't wrong, just a statement with no effect.

If you compile (gcc/g++) with the flag -Wall you'll see.

Answer (score 4):

I guess from this Question's title "After semicolon another command and it compiles" that you think that there can only be one command/statement per line?

As you noticed, this is false. C++ and C are [free-form languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-form_language) (which means that you can arrange the symbols in any way you see fit). The semicolon is just a statement terminator.

You may write `foo();bar();` or

```
foo();
bar();
```

Both (and more) arrangements are totally fine. By the way, that's a feature, not a bug. Some languages (Python, early Fortran) don't have that property.

As others have correctly pointed out, your specific statement is a no-op, a statement without any effect. Some compilers might warn you about that - but no compiler will warn you about multiple statements on one line.

Comment: Python allows multiple statements on the same line.  What Python restricts is where you can break a single statement into multiple lines.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. In this case the problem was the + operator (see answer from Xeo)!

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, that's correct. I meant it more like "Python is not a free-form language". But I can see that this specific "multiple statements on one line" case here is not a good example.