# Why "cout" works weird for "unsigned char"?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, cout, unsigned-char

I have the following code:

```
cvtColor (image, image, CV_BGRA2RGB);
Vec3b bottomRGB;
bottomRGB=image.at<Vec3b>(821,1232);
```

When I display `bottomRGB[0]`, it displays a value greater than 255. What is the reason for this?

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your image has a higher bit depth than 8-bit (which ranges from 0-255 for unsigned int).. For details, please refer to [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth)..

Comment: I have tried converting it into CV_8U too but to no help

Comment: Could you upload the original image (not using the default uploader but on a site where the properties can be preserved)..?

Comment: This is the original image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Greek_Motorway_8_(National_Road_8A)_-_Korinthos_Exit.jpg

Comment: okay, my bad. cout<<bottomRGB[0] was showing wrong value;
int x=bottomRGB[0];
cout<<x;
showed the right value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cout not printing unsigned char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585267/cout-not-printing-unsigned-char)

Comment: *"When I display `bottomRGB[0]`..."* - You should show the output. At the moment people can only guess at the output and the reason for the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have commented, the reason is that you use `cout` to print its content directly. Here I will try to explain to you why this will not work.

```
cout << bottomRGB[0] << endl;
```

### Why `"cout"` works weird for `"unsigned char"`?

It will not work because here `bottomRGB[0]` is a `unsigned char` (with value `218`), `cout` actually will print some *garbage value* (or nothing) as  it is just a ***non-printable* ASCII character** which is getting printed anyway. Note that ASCII character corresponding to `218` is non-printable. Check out [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the ASCII table.

P.S. You can check whether `bottomRGB[0]` is printable or not using [`isprint()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint) as:

```
cout << isprint(bottomRGB[0]) << endl; // will print garbage value or nothing
```

It will print `0` (or `false`) indicating the character is non-printable

---

For your example, to make it work, you need to type cast it first before `cout`:

```
cout << (int) bottomRGB[0] << endl; // correctly printed (218 for your example)
```

Comment: you just need [`cout << +bottomRGB[0]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14365849/995714)