# OpenCV outputing odd pixel values

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to do processing on images with C++ and have been using OpenCV. I've gotten a bit stuck though when it comes to trying to access each pixel individually. I can output the whole gray scaled image just fine using:

`cout << image;`

and get the expected output of values like so:

```
[143, 147, 164, 177, 177, 185, 196, 195, 185, 186, 178, 190, 178, 163, 183...
```

But when I try to output one pixel at a time using:

```
for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0;x < image.cols; ++x) {
        std::cout<<image.at<double>(y, x)<<" ";
    }
            cout << endl;}
```

my output is a bunch of large numbers like these:

```
-2.98684e+18 -1.21685e-83 -1.91543e-113 -1.8525e-59 -2.73052e-127 -2.08731e-35 -3.72066e-103 ...
```

Any thoughts as to what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that those are doubles?

Comment: where does `image` come from? what datatype is it? most probably `<double>` is just the wrong datatype to interpret the values. Try `image.at<unsigned char>(y,x)` or if it is not grayscale but BGR try `image.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x)`.

Comment: did you check your image.type() that should be CV_8U=0 or CV_8UC3=16? Reading video sometimes produces mistakes in terms of number of channels.

Comment: @Micka I'm getting my image from a video frame and then converting it to grayscale like this: `Mat frame;Mat image;`    `VideoCapture vid(".../test_file.mp4");`     `vid.read(frame);`    `cvtColor( frame, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY );`

Comment: @Vlad I also tried using `cout<<gray_image.at<uchar>(y, x)<<" ";`  and now my outputs look like this:  `\217 \223 \244 \261 \261 \271 \304 \303 \271 \272...`

Comment: @Vlad I ran `cout << image.type();' and it outputs `0`. Does this mean it is CV_8U?

Comment: Yes. You should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print all pixels of the image, you can simply use:

```
cout << image << endl;
```

If you want to print a pixel, use:

```
cout << image.at<Vec3b>(y, x) << endl; // for color image
```

or

```
cout << (int) image.at<uchar>(y, x) << endl; // for gray-scale image
```

Note that, in the last line, casting it to `int` is needed. For details, check out [Why "cout" works weird for "unsigned char"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21375753/2589776).

Answer (score 1):

since your values [143, 147, 164, 177...] look like uchar type your Mat type should be either CV_8U=0 or CV_8UC3=16, which you can check with image.type().
So your output should be (as @Micka noted)

```
std::cout<<image.at<uchar>(y, x)<<" "; // gray
or
std::cout<<image.at<Vec3b>(y, x)<<" "; // color
```

In the future just use this in order to stop worrying about the type:

```
Rect rect(0, 0, 10, 10); // print 10x10 block
cout<<image(rect)<<endl;
```

Not to say that knowing type isn't important though.