# Matrix assignement value error in opencv C++ with mat.at<uchar>(i,j)

Tags: c++, opencv, pixel, downsampling

I am learning image processing with OpenCV in C++. To implement a basic down-sampling algorithm I need to work on the pixel level -to remove rows and columns. However, when I assign values with mat.at<>(i,j) other values are assign - things like 1e-38.

Here is the code :

```
Mat src, dst;
src = imread("diw3.jpg", CV_32F);//src is a 479x359 grayscale image

//dst will contain src low-pass-filtered I checked by displaying it works fine
Mat kernel;
kernel = Mat::ones(3, 3, CV_32F) / (float)(9);
filter2D(src, dst, -1, kernel, Point(-1, -1), 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);

// Now I try to remove half the rows/columns result is stored in downsampled
    Mat downsampled = Mat::zeros(240, 180, CV_32F);
for (int i =0; i<downsampled.rows; i ++){
    for (int j=0; j<downsampled.cols; j ++){
        downsampled.at<uchar>(i,j) = dst.at<uchar>(2*i,2*j);
    }
}
```

Since I read here [OpenCV outputing odd pixel values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570107/opencv-outputing-odd-pixel-values) that for cout I needed to cast, I wrote `downsampled.at<uchar>(i,j) = (int) before dst.at<uchar>` but it does not work also.

Comment: First of all, passing `CV_32F` as a second argument of `imread` doesn't make any sense. Next, you make `downsampled` a CV_32F, yet for some reason you access the elements as `uchar`. That means you overwrite one quarter of the bits of a 32bit floating point number with something else.... garbage is the expected result of doing so.

Comment: After your comment, I have changed downsample to CV_U8, the values are in (0, 255) now. However when I try to copy the image only the top left quarter of dst is present in downsampled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `cv::imread` is [cv::ImreadModes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80), so the line:

```
src = imread("diw3.jpg", CV_32F);
```

is not correct; it should probably be:

```
cv::Mat src_8u = imread("diw3.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
src_8u.convertTo(src, CV_32FC1);
```

which will read the image as 8-bit grayscale image, and will convert it to floating point values.

The loop should look something like this:

```
Mat downsampled = Mat::zeros(240, 180, CV_32FC1);
for (int i = 0; i < downsampled.rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < downsampled.cols; j++) {
    downsampled.at<float>(i,j) = dst.at<float>(2*i,2*j);
  }
}
```

note that the argument to `cv::Mat::zeros` is `CV_32FC1` (1 channel, with 32-bit floating values), so `Mat::at<float>` method should be used.