# How can I read the pixel values in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, pixel

I am trying this code to calculate my binary image pixels value by this code :

```
int main()
{
    Mat img;

    img=imread("/home/2b.jpeg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    namedWindow("win", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("win", img);

    for(int i=0; i< img.rows ;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j< img.cols ; j++)
        {
            cout<<setw(10)<<img.at<int>(i,j);
        }
        cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    }

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

But I get 3 types of value: 0, -1 and some big different numbers like (24342234 , 1324244242, etc)

What is the problem? I drew one black line in paint programs and save the image, or download binary image from internet but I get same results!

I thought when I use binary images I must get 0 for white pixels and 255 for black ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should access its pixels with type `uchar` (`unsigned char`) instead of `int`.

And when `cout`, you must explicitly convert to other types like `int` in order to print it correctly because `cout` will work weird when printing `unsigned char` when its value is larger than `127`. Otherwise, it will print some *garbage value* (or nothing) as  it is just a ***non-printable* ASCII character** which is getting printed anyway. Check out [Why "cout" works weird for "unsigned char"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21375753/2589776).

```
cout << setw(10) << (int) img.at<uchar>(i,j);
                    ^^^^^        ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loading it as CV_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE, and accessing pixel values with `image.at< uchar>(y,x)`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked but I want to know why when I choose CV_LOAD_IMAGE_(other options) , it doesn't work true?

Comment: @user3486308 For gray-scale images, it should work for both `CV_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` and `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED` (<0, i.e. loads the image as is (including the alpha channel if present).

Comment: Thank you herohuyongtao.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access integer value while actually your mat is uchar. Try changing inside loop line to:

```
cout<<setw(10)<<img.at<uchar>(i,j);
```

Comment: It will still produce unexpected results when the pixel values is larger than 127. Check out my answer for details.