# Can any body explain it +(+i--)

Tags: java, c++, c

How does `+variable` operate or `+(+variable)` operate?

```
int i=0;
while(+(+i--)!= 0){
     // do 
}
```

Comment: Just curious, is this your code ? If yes, why do you need it ?

Comment: Is that Java or C, or C++?

Comment: Is this [tag:c],[tag:c++] or [tag:java]?

Comment: I got it from a question paper of C

Comment: Then don't tag your question C++ and Java...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called the [unary plus operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation#Unary_negative_and_positive), and it has [(almost) no effect on its argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637005/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-unary-operator-in-c).

By default, it only promotes its argument to an `int`. But since in your example `i` is an `int` already, `+i` is effectively a no-op.

Note that it can additionally be overloaded for custom classes in C++ (not in Java or C).

Comment: It has an effect in an expression though: it applies integral promotion to the argument.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the expression `+variable` is the same as the value of `variable`. The unary `+` operator changes neither the value of the expression nor the value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Both the + operators are unary operator, used for sign purpose and will not impact any functionality of -- (decrement operator).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see what it does is to run it and try it out.
Using `i = 9`, it printed 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.

Logically, what it does then is decrements i after performing the `i != 0` check, but before the code runs.

This, you will find, is synonymous with `while(i-- != 0)` which fits the fact that + does not, in fact, affect your code.

Of course, when dealing with multiple operators on a single variable in a single expression you can quite often get undefined code; Code that may run differently on different compilers. For that sake, you probably shouldn't try using anything as confusing as that in your code.