# lvalue required as increment operand - + unary operator

Tags: c, operators

Can someone explain this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {

   int i = 0,j;
   j=(+i)++;

   return 0;
}
```

which should be

> turning lvalue into rvalue example

according to this:[What is the purpose of the unary plus (+) operator in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637005/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-unary-plus-operator-in-c), 
and gives error: `lvalue required as increment operand`.
How does `+` unary operator work?

also another usage I found in this site:

```
 little known: The unary plus operator can be used as an "decay
 operator": Given int a[10]; int b(void);, then +a is an int pointer
 and +b is a function pointer. Useful if you want to pass it to a
 template accepting a reference
```

can someone explain that as well?

Comment: I think you can use unary + on immediate constants, not on variables. in other words: +3 is OK, +i is NOK

Comment: The error message looks adequate to me. The `++` operator requires an lvalue and `(+i)` is not an lvalue.

Comment: @nivpeled You can use unary `+` on variables. It's just as valid as using a unary `-` on a variable.

Comment: but what does the `+` unary mean then? I only know increment and postincrement, which is not this case (as increment has double `+`), so what does "unary" `+` mean?

Comment: What you're doing is similar to `(0 + i)++`, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: why is this equivalent `(0+1)`? This is not UNARY operator, but I am asking about unary op. And as the link suggest, they used it saying "turning lvalue into rvalue", that is what I do not understand

Comment: You tagged this C, but this is wrong in C: “The unary plus operator can be used as an "decay operator": Given int a[10]; int b(void);, then +a is an int pointer
 and +b is a function pointer.” C 2018 6.5.3.3 1 says the operand of unary `+` shall have arithmetic type, which means the integer and floating types (6.2.5 18). C++ allows this. Avoid using C++ information for C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ok, didn't know it is C++ thing

Comment: @Herdsman: I meant, for your own sake, avoid reading C++ things when learning C. It will cause confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An *lvalue* is an expression that potentially designates an object (bytes in memory). The most common form of lvalue is simply a name: Given `int x`, `float y`, or `char z[10]`, then `x`, `y`, and `z` are lvalues. Another form of lvalue is the result of unary `*`: Given `double *p;`, then `*p` is an lvalue.<sup>1</sup>

When we use lvalues to compute expressions, they are turned into the values of their objects: `x+3` produces three more than whatever value is in `x`. In this expression `x` is used for its **value**. In contrast, in `x = 7;`, `x` is used directly as its lvalue; 7 is written to the bytes in memory, regardless of what value they previously contained.

Since the C standard must specify how compilers behave in technical details, it specifies that, when an lvalue is used in an expression in a place where we want its value, that lvalue is converted to a value. To emphasize that this result is just a number or similar thing and is no longer a reference to memory, it may be called an **rvalue**.

Unary `+` is an operator. When applied to an arithmetic value, it produces the same value. However, it only produces a value, not an lvalue. So applying `+` to an lvalue produces an rvalue.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> This is why an lvalue **potentially** designates an object: `*p` is an lvalue and is treated as such during compilation, but, when the program is executing, `p` might be set to a null pointer, so `*p` would not actually be an object. That would be an error in the program, but it is a run-time error.

Answer (score 1):

> How does + unary operator work?

I believe the unary `-` is simpler to understand, because it actually "does" something "visible". I mean, having `int k = 5` then `-k` is simple - it's turning the positive value `5` into a negative `-5`. The unary `-` "calculates" the negative of it's operand.

The built-in unary `+` just returns the value of its operand. The end. It does nothing. However, applying the unary operator performs [promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) on its argument that are specified in the standard. From [cppreference operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

> The built-in unary plus operator returns the value of its operand. The
>   only situation where it is not a no-op is when the operand has
>   integral type or unscoped enumeration type, which is changed by
>   integral promotion, e.g, it converts char to int or if the operand is
>   subject to lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer
>   conversion.

So `short` value is promoted to `int`. Lvalues are changed to rvalues. Array types decay to a pointer. And a function types decay to a function pointers. [Cppreference value transformations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Value_transformations).

Lvalue ("left value") is something you can assign to. In your code `i` is a variable, you can `i = 1` assign value `1` to `i`. And `2 + 2` is an rvalue ("right value") with value `4` - you can't *"assign"* anything to `2 + 2`, it already has a value.
`+i` is the result of unary `+` applied to `i` - `i` undergoes integer promotions and lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the result of the unary `+` operation has the same value and type as `i` after those transformations.

Comment: It is better to say an operator “produces” some result rather than that it “returns” some result, as it does not perform a function `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from [C11 para 6.5.3.3 - item 2:](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> The  result  of  the  unary `+` operator  is  the  value  of  its 
>   (promoted)  operand.  The  integer promotions are performed on the
>   operand, and the result has the promoted type.

So basically, the effect is almost always a *no-op* with the exceptions of `int` type promotions to its operands. eg,

```
char a = 6;

size_t size_pre_promotion = sizeof(a);
size_t size_post_promotion = sizeof(+a);
```

Where because of the `type` promotion from `char` to `int`, the *size of* the operand `a` grew from `1` to `4`. The *value* of the operand, is returned unchanged.

***From comments:*** *"turning lvalue into rvalue", that is what I do not understand*...

The effect of placing parenthesis around `(+1)`

```
int j = (+i)++;
```

In this expression `(+i)++`, the order of precedence is forced by the parenthesis `()` to perform the transformation of `i` (from the expression `+i`) from being an `lvalue` to an `rvalue`, lexically followed by `++` operator in an attempt to increment the value of `i`. ( `lexically` because this expression will never live beyond compile-time into run-time.)  At this point, `i` is no longer an lvalue, consequently it is no longer assignable, therefore cannot accept the *increment* operation that would normally happen if the operand was still an lvalue.

It is interesting to note by way of illustration that the following expressions are perfectly legal:

```
int j = (+i);//Not attempting to assign value (increment) the operand
             //so the _value_ returned from the operand is successfully assigned
             //to the lvalue `j`;


int j = +i++;//Assigns the i + 1 to j
        //in this case the `++` adds `1` to the operand, then the `+` unary operator returns the incremented value (essentially a no-op at this point),  which in turn is assigned to the _lvalue_ `j`.
```

The unary operator `+` turns an `lvalue` into an `rvalue`.
The terms can essentially be thought of as *assignable* and *not assignable* respectively.

As also shown by these expressions:

```
int j;
&j; //address of an lvalue
```

is legal.  But:

```
&(+j);//cannot _take_ the address of an rvalue
```

is not.

Answer (score 0):

The `++` operator expects its operand to be an *lvalue* - basically, an expression that can designate an object (in the C sense, a chunk of memory that can be used to store a value).

The result of the unary `+` operator, however, is not an lvalue.  In this case, the result of `+i` is just the value `0`, so the expression is equivalent to writing `0++`.  You can't apply the `++` operator to `0` the same way you can't write `0 = 1` - you cannot assign a value to a value, you can only assign a value to an object *through* an lvalue.

Note that following would work:

```
j = +(i++); // or just +i++, precedence is the same
```

You're applying the `+` operator to the result of `i++`, which would be `0` (the postfix `++` evaluates to the *current* value of `i`, and as a *side effect* increments `i`).  The result of `i++` is not an lvalue either, but `+` does not require its operand to be an lvalue.