# Java: Strange String concatenation syntax

Tags: java, string

I hit some strange String concatenation syntax when writing some code and was surprised to find that it compiles.

`quota.setText("Cloud storage: " + used + " (" + + + + quotaUsed / quotaAvailable * 100 + " of " + total);`

The strange part is around the four continuous + operators (I was going to place more strings between them, and I was surprised there were no red squiggly lines underneath them. `quotaUsed` and `quotaAvailable` are `long`s and `used` and `total` are Strings.

Can anyone explain how the system will interpret that statement?

Comment: I think it might be applying the `++` operator once and the unary `+` operator once (making the value positive) and applying concatenation. I am not sure and would need to see output to know.

Comment: @blueblob - Incorrect guess.  The `++` operator cannot have a space in the middle of it.

Comment: @blueblob unary `+` does not "make a value positive".  If `x` is negative, `+x` is still negative.  `Math.abs(x)` would make it positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `+` is going to be the concatenation operator, and the next three will simply be [the unary `+` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3), basically no-ops in this situation. Note that you will be performing integer division on your fraction, so if you write it as

```
(100 * quotaUsed) / quotaAvailable
```

you'll get better precision.

Comment: Thanks, I have heard of but never used the unary plus operator before. This SO answer has a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2624541/473637