# increment of longvalue before conditional operator

Tags: java

I am trying to understand below statement came across code in my project

```
if(name != null && +ssnCount.getLongValue > 0){
    ......
}
```

Can some one explain me +ssCount.getLongValue mean? and difference. Thanks for you time.

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: That is not an increment, just an explicit + sign

Comment: this wouldnt compile. +ssnCount doesnt make any sense. but what do you need?

Comment: Here the `+` is the unary `+` operator.

Comment: difference in using " && ssn.getLongValue"  and" && +ssn.getLongValues""

Comment: There is no difference between these...

Comment: @rgettman why on earth is there a unary + operator... I couldn't see ever writing `int i = +5`

Comment: @Cruncher: [There is *some* purpose.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624410/what-is-the-purpose-of-javas-unary-plus-operator)

Comment: yes that's not a increment,it compiles and yep thats unary operator, may i know the
difference in using " && ssn.getLongValue" and" && +ssn.getLongValues""  ?

Comment: @userJ: I already told: "There is no difference between these..." assuming getLongValue is a field of type long.

Comment: @userJ ake a look at the link StackOverflowException posted (it might answer your question)

Comment: Apart from your recent typo? Nothing.

Comment: @Cruncher It seems useless to me.  I never use it.  The unary numeric promotion it performs seems to be performed without it, when necessary, through assignment conversion, method invocation conversion, or binary numeric promotion.

Comment: @rgettman I just realised, that as a result of this, I can use ++ as both a unary AND binary operator! `int i = 5 ++ 2;` or will java complain about this? EDIT: Nevermind, it recognizes `++` as a symbol on its own and complains. EDIT2: `System.out.println(i+++-+-+2);` Java didn't complain about this. That's pretty scary

Answer (score 4):

[Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

> - Unary plus operator; indicates 
>         positive value (numbers are 
>         positive without this, however)

Actually there is no significant difference between an number variable and an number variable prefixed with the unary operator plus. It is interesting that this operator unboxes wrapped values to primitive types. For example if you declare:

```
Integer a = 10;
```

then using the reference 'a' will be of the reference type Integer, but using '+a' will be of the primitive type int. To be clearer:

```
Integer a = 10;
System.out.println(a instanceof Integer);// true
System.out.println(+a instanceof Integer);// compile time error - unexpected type
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like damaged code. The () after getLongValue is missing (I presume that, with that name, it *was* intended to be a function call), and unary plus is VERY rarely used.

I'd suggest taking it back to whoever wrote it, pointing these issues out to them, and asking them what they had in mind.

Comment: its typo error for my side