# Mathematical expression 1 + + 1 RETURNs 2

Tags: java, math, expression

Mathematical Expression

- 1 + + 1 results 2
- 1 + - 1 returns 0
- 1 + - + 1 returns 0

can anybody know the reason of this. because I only know ++ -- operation but in this case the operator is '+ +' and still not giving an error.

Comment: Do you know unary operators?

Comment: @niklasB yes I know unary operator and I got my answer too. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Its because `+` is also a unary operator which means positive, just like `-` means negative.

```
1 + + 1 =   1 + (+1)  = 1 + 1  = 2
1 + - 1 =   1 + (-1)  = 1 - 1  = 0
1 + - + 1 = 1 + -(+1) = 1 + -1 = 1 - 1 = 0;
```

Comment: @Kent Wait until the "verify you're a human" pop up will appear sometime for you :_(

Comment: @MarounMaroun my experience tells that this "verification" comes often if only code block was written in answer

Comment: @Kent Sometimes you want to be fast and enter details later as edit.

Comment: @MarounMaroun oh, I got you! :-)

Comment: @Kent This prevents my cat from posting answers :D

Comment: @PeterLawrey I really.. really.. didn't expect that. LOL

Comment: @MarounMaroun It has the funniest error handling `O NOES ...` and finishes with `KTHXBYE`

Answer (score 7):

Unary + and - operators at work here.

```
1 + (+1) = 2
1 + (-1) = 0
1 + (-(+1)) = 0
```

[**JLS §15.15.3**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3)

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624410/what-is-the-purpose-of-javas-unary-plus-operator