# What is the role of this plus sign in this Java code?

Tags: java

I met this code:

```
int a = 1;
int k = ++a + a++ + + 1;
System.out.println(k);
```

I think that the compiler will give an error but the result is 5? What is the pourpose of the last '+'(plus) sign? Is it positive sign that marks that 1 is not negative or? And why Java allow this as a valid statement?

Comment: Read about post increment and preincrement!

Comment: Is the question about the `++a+a++` part or just about the `++1`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [explain working of post and pre increment operator in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/explain-working-of-post-and-pre-increment-operator-in-java)

Comment: ++a increments a and returns the new value (2). plus a++ (a++ increments and returns the previous value (2)), plus positive 1. Simplified: 2 + 2 + (+1)

Comment: In C or C++, this would be undefined behavior. In Java, it's just plain ugly.

Comment: You can even _chain_ those unary `+` and `-`: `int k = ++a + a++ + + + + - - + - + - - - + + -+ +- 1;` gives `5` if the number of `-` is even, else `3`

Comment: I am not asking about  post- and pre-increment operators but for the unary plus at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the pourpose of the last '+'(plus) sign?

I'm assuming you understand what the post- and pre-increments are doing here. As for the last `+`: you're using the [unary `+` operator (JLS §15.15.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3), just as in

```
int a = +1;
int b = 1 + +1;
```

> And why Java allow this as a valid statement?

That's not really a meaningful question. The correct answer to it is "because the JLS says it's allowed". As for why *that's* the case, we can only speculate, but it makes sense to incorporate a unary plus for the sake of symmetry with unary minus. Unary plus can also be used for numeric promotion; from the link above:

> Unary numeric promotion ([§5.6.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)) is performed on the operand. The type of the unary plus expression is the promoted type of the operand. The result of the unary plus expression is not a variable, but a value, even if the result of the operand expression is a variable.
>
> At run time, the value of the unary plus expression is the promoted value of the operand.

Answer (score 8):

The statement is effectively grouped like this:

```
int k = (++a) + (a++) + (+1);
```

The `+1` is a valid number literal, just like `-1`, but it is equivalent to simply `1`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's just a unary plus operator. Granted, [its practical uses are fairly limited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2624541/1321716), but it's valid Java so the compiler doesn't complain.

With parentheses:

```
int k = (++a) + (a++) + (+1);
```

*Side note: please never write actual code with these pre/post-increment combinations.* :-P