# Why does "hello" + + '/' + "world" == "hello47world"?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

For this C#, `a==true`:

```
bool a = "hello" +   '/' + "world" == "hello/world";
```

And for this C#, `b==true`:

```
bool b = "hello" + + '/' + "world" == "hello47world";
```

I'm wondering how this can be, and more importantly, why did the C# language architects choose this behavior?

Comment: Everyone in this thread: "`+` is a unary operatior that converts the `char` to an `int`". No-one in this thread: "Here's why it does that..."

Comment: @Rawling Guffa's answer does, in the second sentence. He's saying that the first `+` in `+ + '/'` is the very same operator that makes it possible to write "1" as "+1". The conversion then happens, I presume, because there's no "+ char" operator, but `char` can be implicitly converted to int.

Comment: @fgp I've got a whole post about why the `int` one specifically but I doubt anyone cares :)

Comment: @Rawling Enlighten me ;-)

Comment: @fgp Welp, there you go. It's thrilling stuff.

Comment: I used to think C# was a [relatively](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) sane language!

Comment: @leftaroundabout no, in this sense it's similar to [C, C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3903383/995714), [Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16015448/995714) or [Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1133814/995714) because they all use unary + to promote a char to int

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: but C and C++ don't just allow “concatenating” arbitrary to-string-able types with `+` to strings. I.e. `s + +'/'` gives a clear compiler error, only `s + '/'` concatenates the char to the string. (For `std::string s`, that is. C doesn't allow this at all... its string-pointer arithmetics of course have the potential to go even more horribly wrong...)

Answer (score 50):

The second `+` is converting the `char` to an `int`, and adding it into the string. The ASCII value for `/` is 47, which is then converted to a string by the other + operator.

The `+` operator before the slash implicitly casts it to an int. See [+ Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx) on MSDN and look at the "unary plus".

> The result of a unary + operation on a numeric type is just the value of the operand.

I actually figured this out by looking at what the `+` operators were actually calling. (I think this is a ReSharper or VS 2015 feature)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice, Resharper always blows my mind again and again! Go Team JetBrain!

Comment: Do you know which Resharper option see this operator intellisense usage? It doesn't show on me by default.

Comment: @SonerGönül I just did a fresh install of VS and ReSharper so I am on all default settings. All I did was hover over the + and it appeared.

Comment: "Because the + is before the slash, the value before incrementing is returned." <- ??? This expression contains neither the pre- nor the post-increment `++` operator, so why are you mentioning them? The `+` here is the unary `+` operator, which is the identity on integers.

Comment: @Cyral What are the versions of VS and Resharper? I use VS Ultimate 2013 and Reshaper 9.0 update 1 and there is no even option for operators under Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> Intellisense -> Autopopup section.

Comment: It may be a feature of VS 2015 which I am using. (Also on Resharper 9)

Comment: I don't have Re, and it still works for me, hence it's VS 2015.

Comment: Yes. Just check C# built-in conversions and operators. The `operator +` in C# has many built-in overloads. The relevant *binary* one here is `string operator +(string x, object y)` which calls `ToString()` on the `object` argument `y`, and concatenates the two strings. For the [*unary* overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691365.aspx) it is important to notice that no unary overload takes in a `char`. However a `char` is implicitly convertible to `ushort` an "larger" integer types. That includes `int`, and the best overload for `+'/'` is this one `int operator +(int x)`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Actually, the binary string operator isn't used. The compiler replaces it with a call to the `String.Concat(object,object,object)` method, which calls `ToString` on each operand.

Comment: @Guffa I was considering this on a C# spec level. The C# spec is defined to have an operator like the one I describe, and that is the reason why this is legal C# and works the way it does. However, on the BCL level, the [`String` operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986396.aspx) do not even include a `+` (or `op_Addition` as it would have been called as an IL method). So the C# compiler "translates" it into a call to `Concat` like you say. But knowing this is not helpful when trying to understand the C# syntax!

Answer (score 26):

That's because you are using the unary operator `+`. It's similar to the unary operator `-`, but it doesn't change the sign of the operand, so the only effect it has here is to implicitly convert the character `'/'` into an `int`.

The value of `+'/'` is the character code of `/`, which is 47.

The code does the same as:

```
bool b = "hello" + (int)'/' + "world" == "hello47world";
```

Comment: But I wonder what was the motivation to let unary `+` be defined on `char` at all. I would probably make it a compile-time error. If someone needs the numerical value, why not be explicit and use a cast? (So, basically, why does `char` have _implicit_ conversion to `int`?)

Comment: @Vlad: Eric Lippert has written something about that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/01/why-does-char-convert-implicitly-to-ushort-but-not-vice-versa.aspx

Comment: @Guffa: The matching part of the text is "_There is a long tradition in C programming of treating characters as integers -- to obtain their underlying values, or to do mathematics on them._", which I would read as "legacy from C times where everything were a number". As of now, with non-English locales (so valid letters are not a range any more) and Unicode and its quirks (so upcase is not a bit operation any more, and two chars together don't necessarily produce two-place string), the idea of using numeric character values is increasingly less and less attractive.

Comment: @Vlad: Yes, that is true. The motivation for allowing the implicit conversion is that it's not harmful, like allowing implicit conversion from a number to a char would be. The OP has found a combination of thee special cases that together gives an unexpected result; the rarely used unary plus operator causing implicit conversions, the implicit conversion from char to int, and the concatenation of strings and ints. If any of those needed to be made explicit, the code would not work that way.

Answer (score 16):

Why, I hear you ask, is the `char` specifically treated to the operator `int operator +(int x)` rather than one of the [many other fine unary `+` operators available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691365.aspx)?:

- The [unary operator overload resolution rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691325.aspx) say to look at user-defined unary operators first, but since `char` doesn't have any of those, the compiler looks at the *predefined* unary `+` operators.
- Obviously [none of those](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691365.aspx) take a `char` either, so the compiler uses the [overload resolution rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336.aspx) to decide which operator (of `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `float`, `double` `decimal`) is the best.
- Those resolution rules says to look at which is the [best function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338.aspx)... which pretty much says to look at which argument type offers the [best conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691339.aspx) from `char`.
- `int` beats out `long`, `float` and `double` because you can [implicitly convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) `int` to those types and not back.
- `int` beats `uint` and `ulong` because... the best conversion rule says it does.

Comment: Brilliant, this explains why the C# architects designed it to work the way that it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How this occurs is an implicit cast (*"A char can be implicitly converted to ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal."* (**[char<sup>MSDN</sup>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx)**).

The most simple form of the reproduction can be found as

```
int slash = +'/'; // 47
```

Char internally is a struct. *"Purpose: This is the value class representing a Unicode character"* (**[char.cs<sup>ms referencesource</sup>](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/char.cs,02f2b1a33b09362d)**), and the reason the struct can be implicitly cast is because it implements the [IConvertible](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/iconvertible.cs,09e9f8f17849c7ce) interface.

```
public struct Char : IComparable, IConvertible
```

Specifically, with this piece of code

```
/// <internalonly/>
int IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) {
    return Convert.ToInt32(m_value);
}
```

The `IConvertible` interface states in a comment in code

> // The IConvertible interface represents an object that contains a value. This
>   // interface is implemented by the following types in the System namespace:
>   // Boolean, Char, SByte, Byte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64,
>   // Single, Double, Decimal, DateTime, TimeSpan, and String.

Looking back to the purpose of struct (to be a value representative of a unicode character), it is clear that the intention for this behavior in the language was to provide a way for the value to be converted to supported types. `IConvertible` goes on to state

> // The implementations of IConvertible provided by the System.XXX value classes
>   // simply forward to the appropriate Value.ToXXX(YYY) methods (a description of
>   // the Value class follows below). In cases where a Value.ToXXX(YYY) method
>   // does not exist (because the particular conversion is not supported), the
>   // IConvertible implementation should simply throw an InvalidCastException.

Which is explicitly stating that conversions which are not supported throw exceptions. It is also explicitly stated that converting a character to an integer will give the integer value of that character.

> The ToInt32(Char) method returns a 32-bit signed integer that represents the UTF-16 encoded code unit of the value argument. **[Convert.ToInt32 Method (Char)<sup>MSDN</sup>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx)**

All in all, the reasoning for the behavior seems to be self evident. The integer value of the char has meaning as a "UTF-16 encoded code unit". The backslash's value is 47.

As a result of of the value cast present and because `char` is a built-in numeric type, the implicit cast to integer from the plus sign is done at compile time. This can be seen with the reuse of the above simple example in a small program (linqpad works to test this)

```
void Main()
{
    int slash = +'/';
    Console.WriteLine(slash);
}
```

Becomes

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s    2F 
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // slash2
IL_0003:  ldloc.0     // slash2
IL_0004:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0009:  ret
```

Where the `'/'` is simply converted to the hexidecimal value of 2F (47 in decimal) and then used from there.

Answer (score 1):

```
+ '/'
```

Gives you the `UTF-16 (decimal) 47` character code of the character "/" and @Guffa already explained you why.

Comment: Thanks @Guffa for point out that error. C# use UTF-16 as the default encoding for strings in .NET

Comment: @Guffa Interesting... what happens if you have `+''`? Does it result in a syntax error?

Comment: @Rhymoid It results in an error. "Too many characters in character literal"

Comment: @Cyral Makes sense. For those wondering: that emoji lies in the SMP, so UTF-16 encodes it using surrogate pairs (in this case: `U+D83C U+DF81`), which the compiler counts as "two characters" (which is so far from the truth that it ain't even wrong).

Answer (score 1):

As In c# a char is expressed in single quotes i.e. '/' in your case, the + operator in front of char is acting as a unary operator and asks the compiler to provide the UTF value of the char '/' which is 47.