# Meaning of a single plus sign in an array

Tags: java, android

Following [this tutorial](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/) I saw that at the end in the MainActivity.java there is an array that I understand but dont know what a single + sign does at the end

```
String Slecteditem= itemname[+position];
```

I remove the + and I think it works the same way, but not sure if there is a purpose that I cant see.

Comment: probably a typo...:)

Comment: @Reimeus Given the difficulty of entering this particular typo (Shift required), I found Sergey's answer intriguing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`+` is the unary plus operator. It's unnecessary here as array indices can never be negative

Answer (score 3):

It's a [unary positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation#C_family_of_languages), so your intuition was correct `+position` is the same as `position`.

Answer (score 3):

I bet the author of that code was just writing too much JavaScript lately. In JavaScript, this is a popular trick because unary `+` is the most concise way to convert a string to a number. In Java, unary plus can only be used for [more obscure conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624410/what-is-the-purpose-of-javas-unary-plus-operator), but that doesn't apply here because `position` is already an `int`, and I won't recommend ever writing such code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

single positive(+) and single negative(-) signs in java are unary operators meaning they are used for indices, that is to depict that a number is either positive or negative. your code will still work since array values are never negative