# Why int i1 = -+0007 is same as int i2 = +-0007 ? And why both plus-minus compile fine?

Tags: java

What rules govern such unexpected behaviour?

```
int i1 = -+0007;
int i2 = +-0007;
System.out.println(i1);  // output: -7
System.out.println(i2);  // output: -7

    int i3 = +-+0007;   // -7
    int i4 = -+-0007;   // 7
```

I understand that unary sign operator is right-associative. But if minus goes first (rightmost), it seems that next **plus (to the left) does not change sign from minus to plus (i.e. does nothing!)**. But second **minus changes sign (from negative to positive).**

Besides we cannot use ++ or -- anywhere in this sequence of +-+-+- (+--+ is compile error: rightmost + (or leftmost +) is wrong operand of -- operation).

Comment: Note that `++` and `--` are actual operators (while `-+` nor `+-` isn't).

Comment: `+` doesn't mean "make it positive" any more than `-` means "make it negative".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unary `-` changes the sign. Unary `+` doesn't, it's mostly pointless, it does an [unary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3), you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624410/what-is-the-purpose-of-javas-unary-plus-operator) for some more details about it.

So in your first line:

```
int i1 = -+0007;
```

`+` does nothing `-` changes to `-7`

Second line:

```
int i2 = +-0007;
```

`-` changes to `-7` `+` does nothing

`+--+` is a compile error because `--` is a different operator that can only operate on a variable. Something like the following will work:

```
int b = 1;
int a = -++b; // increment b by 1, change the sign and assign to a
System.out.println(a); // prints -2
```

You can use parenthesis or add space to make `+--+` compile

```
int i = +-(-+7); // will be equal to 7 because only the 2 `-` change the sign
int i = +- -+7;
```

Answer (score -1):

It has tog do with Maths. If you multiply a negative and a positive number, the result is negative. If you multiply two negative numbers, the result is positive.

So, the `-` or `+` could also be written as:

```
-…: (-1) * …
+…:  (1) * …
```

Comment: It is just the mathematical explanation. You could also say, `-` changes the sign, and `+` does not.