# Why is `+ 1` a valid expression in Java?

Tags: java

The following code block

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( + 1);
  }
}
```

Compiles on java 1.8.

When this code is run `1` is printed.

Same with `System.out.println(+ + 1);`

However `++1` fails to compile.

`+ + "str"` fails to compile.

`+ + true` fails to compile.

So it looks like it is supported only for int, long and double.

What is the reason that this expression is valid for the above data types?

Comment: What do you expect to happen by doing `++1`?

Comment: `++1` failing is fine since there is no variable to increment and store, however I am wondering why `+ + 1` compiles.

Comment: BTW I stumbled upon this while adding string with a character, that is "test" + + '}' is a valid expression and I got to thinking why its allowed.

Comment: `1` is a v+ `1` that can also be written like `+1` and similarly -ve can be written as `-1`, (but not `+1` is an expression but just `1` is a literal) for negation en expression result you can put `-` minus in front of expression as `-exp` => to negate result of expression `+1` you can write `-+1` ...now this should give you an idea why `++1` is valid and also `+-1` or `-----1` is valid

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i think you have misspelled your comment in the end b/w invalid and valid. '....why ++1 is valid and also +-1 or -----1 is valid ' .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unary plus expression. It is here just to compliment unary minus expression.

Only numerical type suports it because for other types it doesn't make any sense.

`++1` is not compiles because `++` is increment expression and requires variable or field as sub expression.

Comment: Got it, this answer helps as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624410/what-is-the-purpose-of-javas-unary-plus-operator

Answer (score 1):

`+1` is not an expression, it's an explicit way to say positive `1`. On the other hand, `++1` is a pre-increment expression on variable `1`, which doesn't exist, nor is it legal to have a variable name start with a digit. `+ + 1` is equivalent of `+(+(1))`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `+` separated by space is treated as unary operator

For example

```
- - 5 => -(-5) => 5
```

Similarly

```
+ + 5 => +(+5) => 5
```