# Why is my charAt when printed giving me a number instead of a letter

Tags: java

When using the code below, I am a beginner testing what String methods do. Though, whenever using hello and using a char i to represent 0, why is it not printing out h and instead 104. And if there is a reason why it is printing 104, why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "hello";
        char i  = hello.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your are printing `+i` instead of `i`

Comment: To expand on that:correct comment (which should IMO be written up as the answer) `+i` widens the `char` to an `int`, which is formatted differently.

Comment: Specifically, I think the unary operator `+` does what most other math does in Java: it returns an integer, not a `char`.  You'd have to convert the number back: `System.out.println( (char)(+i) );`

Comment: TLDR: Don't use `+` with a `char`.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan Please wirte that as an answer.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624410/what-is-the-purpose-of-javas-unary-plus-operator#2624541

Answer (score 3):

The '+' is messing you up.  Remove that one character and you'll get the result you desire:

```
class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String hello = "hello";
        char i  = hello.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
h
```

104 is the ASCII value that represents the `'h'` character.  I couldn't have told you this in advance, but apparently putting a'+' in front of a character value causes it to be converted to an integer that is its ASCII value.