# Is the uplus function useful?

Tags: matlab

This is a rhetorical question about the [`uplus`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uplus.html) function in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), or its corresponding operator, the unary plus `+`.

Is there a case where this operator is useful? Even better, is there a case where this operator is necessary?

Comment: I can't say I've ever had to use it, or even thought of using it before. In some cases it might be useful for the sake of clarity to the reader. This [similar question in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727516/what-does-the-unary-plus-operator-do) might be of interest.

Comment: I don't think you actually meant *rhetorical* so I took the liberty of answering this. ;-)

Comment: @horchler This is not a practical question on a specific problem, but more a topic on which I wanted to get your toughts. Thanks for answering, anyway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not necessary, a language without a unary plus does not allow to write `+1`. Obviously you could also write `1` but when importing data which always writes the `+` or `-` it's very nice to have.

Searching some source codes, I found a curious use of `+`

```
A=+A
```

which replaced the code:

```
if ~isnumeric(A)
    A=double(A);
end
```

It casts chars and logicals to double, but all numeric data types remain untouched.

Comment: Well, there is a lot of things that is not necessary. For example: classes, structs, cells, functions ... Still they make it easier to do programming. So as you say that it can be used to make it simpler when importing some data it is an as good reason as any to have it. Anyway +1 for providing a good reason

Comment: I was just typeing my answer with the cast use!

Comment: Yes, importing data is a key application. Sometimes it's easier in code to do `+` or `-` instead of nothing or `-`. `printf` style functions have the option always putting a leading sign. The string output from Matlab's symbolic math (before it's converted back to `sym` class) also often includes prefixed `+` operators, presumably because it's easier for MuPAD to parse.

Comment: @Daniel: Very nice cast usage. I'm waiting a bit to see if anyone has other ideas before marking the topic as solved.

Comment: Personally, I would rather read the longer explicit if-statement version every day of the week, rather than an obscure `A=+A` that will leave me puzzled about what it really does.

Answer (score 8):

It can be useful when defining new numeric types.

Suppose you define quaternion and overload `uplus`:

```
classdef quaternion
    ...
end
```

Then in your code you can write:

```
x = quaternion(...);
y = [+x, -x];
z = +quaternion.Inf;
t = -quaternion.Inf;
```

If you don't you cannot have same syntax as for other numeric.

PS: To the question "is it useful" (in the sence mandatory for some syntaxes) ... well I can't find any reason ... but sometimes writting '+x' make things clearer when reading back the code.

Comment: Somewhat related to your answer: I sometimes write `+Inf` in comments and documentation for my code as I think it comes across more clearly (and makes it obvious that `Inf` is not a misspelling of something else).

Comment: @horchler +1 for the +Inf

Comment: @CrazyRat: where would Stack Overflow be without the unary plus?!

Comment: @horchler You are right, the unary plus completely makes sense in SO !

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this fully constitutes "useful" or if it's the best programming practice, but in some cases, one may wish to use the [unary](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) `+` for symmetry/clarity reasons. There's probably a better example, but I'm thinking of something like this:

```
A = [+1 -1 +1;
     -1 +1 -1;
     +1 -1 +1];
```

As for the [`uplus`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uplus.html) function, it's kind of a [NOOP](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) for numeric operations. If one writes a function that requires a function handle input to specify an operation to perform, it *might* be useful to have do nothing option.

Lastly, numeric operators can be [overloaded](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html) for other classes. The `uplus` function could have more use in other built-in classes or even one you might want write yourself.

Comment: OK, I get the convenience/clarity point, though it's not the meaning of "useful" I was thinking of. The overloading usage is interesting. Can you think of a case where the `uplus` syntax would be more handy than a regular method ? Besides the fact that it takes less characters to write ...