# Why are multiple, consecutive plusses allowable syntax in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parsing, syntax, abstract-syntax-tree

Does anyone know why this works in MATLAB?

```
>> 1 ++ 2
ans =
     3
```

Coming from coding in C, python, Java etc, I find it most counterintuitive that this should work at all. Presumably there's something important about the parser that I don't understand?

Comment: `1++++++++++2` works as well...

Comment: `1 ++ 2 = 1 + (+2) = 1 + 2 = 3`... How else could this possibly be interpreted? There's no ambiguity with consecutive `+`/`-` signs. See [unary plus](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uplus.html) (and unary minus).

Comment: This also works in python

Comment: @JETM similar reason, yes, but the difference between `++++` and `+ + + +` working is different from Java, since there you need white space between.

Comment: For additional fun, compare `1 ++ 2` and `[1 ++ 2]`

Comment: @LuisMendo That's crazy. `[1 ++ 2]` is `[1 2]` whereas `[1 + + 2]` is `3`  ...  :'-( Can anyone explain that...

Comment: And worse, `[1 ++ + 2]` is `[1 2]`, but `[1 + ++ 2]` is 3. Grim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a difference between [`plus`](https://mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018b/matlab/ref/plus.html) and [`uplus`](https://mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018b/matlab/ref/uplus.html). I suspect MATLAB takes the first `+` as `plus`, and all the others as `uplus`. Since `uplus` is by default just "return what's behind", you add `1` and `2`, and use a lot of "return what's behind" in between.

```
a=2;
c=+a % unitary plus
c =
     2
1+2 % addition
ans =
     3
1+++2 % addition and two uplusses
ans =
     3
```

The reason `uplus` exists is to allow operator overloading in classes. The same works in other languages, e.g. [in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/727518/5211833), to allow for operator overloading in confined classes.

---

The other reason mentioned in that C# thread is that is changes unsigned shorts to integers, which is not the case for MATLAB:

```
d=uint8(1)
d =
  uint8
   1
+d
ans =
  uint8
   1
a=+d
a =
  uint8
   1
```

It does, however, convert a boolean to a double, thanks to [Cris Lunego](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555709/why-are-multiple-consecutive-plusses-allowable-syntax-in-matlab#comment92051387_52556168) for pointing that out:

```
+true
ans =
     1
+false
ans =
     0
```

---

The following however remains a mystery to me, inspired by [Sanjay Manohar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555709/why-are-multiple-consecutive-plusses-allowable-syntax-in-matlab#comment92077625_52555709):

```
>> [1 ++ 2]
ans =
     1     2 % Two unary plusses
>> [1 + + 2]
ans =
     3 % A normal plus and a unary one
>> [1++2]
ans =
     3 % A normal plus and a unary one
```

The same works with multiple plusses, `[1 +++..+++ 2]`, so with all plusses consecutively in the middle generates `[1 2]`, all other combinations (as far as I tested) result in `3`. I asked a separate question about this: [Why do the plus and unary plus behave strange in array syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52664282/5211833)

Comment: Ah yes, silly me. It seems that `++` isn't lexed as a single token. I guess this means the lexer and parser aren't separate things in Matlab? I had never noticed this, and it doesn't seem to be a very common feature among languages?

Comment: @SanjayManohar I have no idea what a lexer or parser is; `++` is not, as you might expect from other languages, "add one". Basically MATLAB's interpreter tries to use a plus first as addition, and once that doesn't work, it defaults to the unary plus, which in turn doesn't do anything with the input. MATLAB does not require white space; `1*exp(i+3/5)` is just as valid as `1 *    exp(   i        +  3      /      5 )`

Comment: @Sanjay Manohar MATLAB doesn't have a `++` AFAIK, so there's no problem for the lexer here.

Comment: For those interested: Unarticulated plus also converts a Boolean to a double: `+true` is `1.0` (though that conversion would also happen in any other arithmetic context).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks! But it doesn't promote: `class(+uint8(1))` gives `uint8`.

Comment: @JETM Yes that is crucial - the fact that Matlab *doesn't* have `++` is necessary for this to work.

Comment: @Sanjay: True, it returns the same class if the input is numeric, but converts to double if the input is Boolean. `uint8(1)+1` also returns an 8-bit integer. MATLAB always keeps the class of the non-double numeric values, I believe.