# Why do the plus and unary plus behave strange in array syntax?

Tags: arrays, matlab, parsing, unary-operator

Following [this question on the plus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52555709/5211833) I have a follow-up question. We know the difference between [`plus`](https://mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018b/matlab/ref/plus.html) and [`uplus`](https://mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018b/matlab/ref/uplus.html), and thus that `1+2` resolves to `3`, just as `1++2` or even `1++++++++2`. The strange thing happens in array syntax, consider this example:

```
>> [1 ++ 2]
ans =
     1     2 % Two unary plusses
>> [1 + + 2]
ans =
     3 % A normal plus and a unary one
>> [1++2]
ans =
     3 % A normal plus and a unary one
```

The same works with multiple plusses, `[1 +++..+++ 2]`, so with all plusses consecutively in the middle generates `[1 2]`, all other combinations (as far as I tested) result in `3`.

As far as I know spaces are of limited importance in MATLAB; `exp(3*x/y)` is the same as `exp( 3 * x / y )`. There is a use for them in creating arrays: `[1 2]` will generate a 1 *-by-* 2 array, and there are a few other uses, but separating operators is not one of them.

Therefore my question: Why do `[1 ++ 2]` and `[1 + + 2]` resolve differently?

*Note that the [`minus`](https://mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018b/matlab/ref/minus.html) and [`uminus`](https://mathworks.com/help/releases/R2018b/matlab/ref/uminus.html) have the same behaviour, and that the parser is magic enough to parse `[1;;;3++ + + +--+ + ++4,;;;,;]` perfectly fine to `[1;7]`.*

Comment: But we all know that this is a pointless question because we'd never use syntax like this in our code, right? Right?

Comment: Actually, I think that the parser should error out (or at least produce a warning) on ambiguous syntax like this. And I think it was a mistake to allow a space as an element separator in arrays. Please use commas!

Comment: @Cris wrong language ;)

Answer (score 6):

My suspicion is that this has to do with how numeric literals are parsed. In particular, consider the following complex examples:

```
>> [1+2i]

ans =

   1.0000 + 2.0000i

>> [1 +2i]

ans =

   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 2.0000i

>> [1 + 2i]

ans =

   1.0000 + 2.0000i
```

There's a conflict between space as an array separator and space as a part of a complex number.

I believe the parser was written such that it tries to make sense of complex numbers (versus complex arrays) as reasonably as possible. This can easily lead to non-trivial behaviour in parsing expressions involving addition/subtraction and whitespace.

---

To be a bit more specific:

`1 ++ 2` might parse as `1 +2`, since multiple unary pluses are still a unary plus, and a unary plus can only act on the `2`.

But `1 + + 2` might parse as `1 + (+ 2)` where the latter plus is consumed as a unary plus, leaving `1 + 2` which is a single "complex" number.

---

A further follow-up after [an inquisitive comment from @Adriaan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52664282/why-do-the-plus-and-unary-plus-behave-strange-in-array-syntax/52664409#comment92260943_52664409):

> [...] `[1 ++ + 2]` is `[1 2]`, but `[1 + ++ 2]` is `3`

So my proper guess would be that the parser moves from right to left.

- `[1 ++ + 2]` -> `[1 ++ (+ 2)]` -> `[1 ++ 2]`, versus
- `[1 + ++ 2]` -> `[1 + (++ 2)]` -> `[1 + 2]`.

This would also imply that any combination of `[1 + ...2]` (where there is only one plus in the first connected block of pluses) will give you `[3]` whereas if the first block of pluses contains two or more you will get `[1 2]`. A few pseudorandom tests seemed to verify this behaviour.

Of course until The MathWorks makes their parser open-source or documented we can only guess.

Comment: So for the case `[1 ++ + 2]` is `[1 2]`, but `[1 + ++ 2]` is `3`, the parser reads a unary plus in the first case, making all subsequent plusses unary, whereas in the second case it reads addition, followed by unary plusses?

Comment: @Adriaan my guess would be that it goes from right to left. `[1 ++ + 2]` -> `[1 ++ (+ 2)]` -> `[1 ++ 2]`, versus `[1 + ++ 2]` -> `[1 + (++ 2)]` -> `[1 + 2]`.

Comment: @Adriaan see my updated post with a proper-ish hypothesis.