# Square brackets operator in Matlab without comma between its two values

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix-indexing

I'm having a hard time figuring out what this code does, because googling square brackets doesn't yield appropriate results for the way the search engine works.

`id2` is a `1x265` array (so basically a 1d vector with 265 values)

`m` is a `1x245` array (so basically a 1d vector with 245 values)

```
id2 = id2([m m(end)+1]);
```

For what I've seen so far, there always is a comma between the first and second value in the square brackets.

If it was

`id2 = id2[m, m(end)+1]`

In my little Matlab experience I would have known its meaning but this is not the case, never seen this one before.

The square brackets are also enclosed in brackets `( )` after `id2` so this makes me think that

`id2 = id2([m m(end)+1])` and `id2 = id2[m, m(end)+1]` are two completely different things.

Can you explain me what that code does please?

Comment: Just as a funny side note: [MATLAB's array syntax can be even weirder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52664282/5211833)

Comment: lol what? They don't like it plain and simple for sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[1, 2]` and `[1 2]` are equivalent. Either a comma or a space can denote element separation when building arrays using square brackets.
Indexing, using parentheses `()`, has to be done using commas: `A(3,1)`, not `A(3 1)`. The same holds for argument lists in functions: `mean(A,[],1)` needs commas to separate the various parameters.

`id2 = id2([m m(end)+1]);` should then be clear: you build an array `[m m(end)+1]`, i.e. you take `m` and add one extra element, `m(end)+1`, to its end. These should be integers, presumably, since the look like they are indexing into `id2`. Given the above, `id2 = id2([m, m(end)+1]);` is exactly equivalent.

I can recommend reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833) on the various ways of indexing in MATLAB.

Comment: thank you. It was getting so much confusing for me since I'm working both with Matlab and Python at the same time and one use to index with `( )` while the other with `[ ]`! Also the fact that Matlab can use commas or not for certain things makes it even more confusing