# Why do C and C++ allow the expression (int) + 4*5?

Tags: c++, c, casting, language-lawyer

```cpp
(int) + 4*5;
```

Why is this *(adding a type with a value)* possible? (tried with g++ and gcc.)

I know that it doesn't make sense (and has no effect), but I want to know why this is possible.

Comment: same as `(int)-4*5`

Comment: There is a useful tool called `cppinsights` that helps to understand how the code looks from the compiler frontend perspective. It also has an online version, you can see what it tells about [your example](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=aW50IG1haW4oKQp7CgkoaW50KSArIDQqNTsKfQ==&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0) (the same 'parenthesization' as the answers your were given)

Comment: This statement is equivalent to `+(int)+ 4*5;` and `-(int)- 4*5;` and `-+-+-(int)-+-+- 4*5;` and less poetically `;`

Comment: @Ernest Bredar: The thing is, typecasting makes perfect sense when used in an expression, e.g. "num = (int) + 4*5" (even though it's redundant in this particular case).  But why can you have an expression without an assignment?  And gcc doesn't complain if the expression is just "+4 * 5;"

Comment: What part puzzles you? For all I know, you are asking why you are allowed to write 5 without indicating the sign.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the unary plus operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727516/what-does-the-unary-plus-operator-do)

Comment: @jamesqf *why can you have an expression without an assignment?* So you can call functions that return a value that you don't need without having to do a pointless assignment. Would you prefer to be forced to write `char_count = printf("something\n");`?

Comment: Shouldn't C++ warn you that C-type casts are not recommended in C++?

Comment: @PM 2Ring: A function call is not the same as an expression, and a compiler had better be able to distinguish between the two :-)

Comment: @jamesqf It's a kind of expression, i.e., all function calls are expressions, but not vice versa. So why should the language definition permit unassigned function calls, but not others? Also, an assignment is itself an expression, which allows chained assignments, but the chain has to stop somewhere. But here's a simpler example: `i++;`

Comment: No, @MrLister. They're perfectly legal in C++, and part of the language specification. Certain compilers have optional warnings for this (like GCC's `-Wold-style-cast`), but they're more like code *style* warnings (a la Lint) than actual compiler warnings. Microsoft's compiler has no such warning, although it does have some style/code analysis tools that might be able to be configured accordingly.

Comment: This question was reposted without attribution on Quora: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-C-and-C-allow-the-expression-int-4-5

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The `+` here is [unary `+` operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation), not the [binary addition operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation). There's no addition happening here.

Also, the syntax `(int)` is used for typecasting.

You can re-read that statement as

```
(int) (+ 4) * 5;
```

which is parsed as

```
((int) (+ 4)) * (5);
```

which says,

1. Apply the unary `+` operator on the integer constant value `4`.
2. typecast to an `int`
3. multiply with operand `5`

This is similar to `(int) (- 4) * (5);`, where the usage of the unary operator is more familiar.

In your case, the unary `+` and the cast to `int` - both are redundant.

Comment: "Casting", not "typecasting". Typecasting is something that happens to actors.

Comment: `(+ 4)` is not *make the operand `+4`*, it means apply the unary `+` to operand `4`, which indeed is a no-op in the OP's case, but could cause integer promotion or array decay in other circumstances. For example `char c = 0; sizeof +c == sizeof c` is probably false and `sizeof +"a"` is probably not 2.

Comment: "both are redundant" - the whole thing is redundant, just like `42;` :-)

Comment: I see nothing wrong with using the term Type Casting.
It seems [I'm not the only one](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/typecasting/).

Comment: @Ben Typecasting is not type casting.

Comment: Furthermore, the past participle of "cast" is "cast", [unless you're in the 1500s](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94565/can-casted-be-the-past-tense-of-cast).

Comment: The word "typecasting" is _completely_ and _entirely_ understood in this context. Why would anyone think it relates to actors? What pointless bikeshedding!

Comment: Don't the number constants have a type?

Comment: @PeterMortensen They do. Here it'd be `int`.

Answer (score 41):

This is interpreted as `((int)(+4)) * 5`. That is, an expression `+4` (a unary plus operator applied to a literal `4`), cast to type `int` with a C-style cast, and the result multiplied by `5`.