# Plus char ('+') before constant

Tags: javascript, node.js

One question: Which means plus(+) before `process.env`?

```
port: process.env.POSTGRESQL_PORT ? +process.env.POSTGRESQL_PORT : 5432
```

Comment: Well, have you try it to find out yourself?

Comment: It is the [unary plus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727516/what-does-the-unary-plus-operator-do/727518) that converts an operand to a number.

Comment: This is too in typescript or javascript?

Comment: @halohalohalo Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [unary plus (+) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus).

It precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to convert it into a number, if it isn't already.

```js
const x = 1;
const y = -1;

console.log(+x);
// expected output: 1

console.log(+y);
// expected output: -1

console.log(+'');
// expected output: 0

console.log(+true);
// expected output: 1

console.log(+false);
// expected output: 0

console.log(+'hello');
// expected output: NaN
```