# Is it safe to use the unary plus operator?

Tags: c#, unary-operator

I saw code that goes like this:

```cs
double d = GetDouble();
DoSomething(+d);
DoSomething(-d);
```

I know in it is potentially dangerous and not recommended in C++ to use the unary `+` just to emphasize that the value is positive. `<EDIT>`"just to emphasize that the value is positive" was a mental shortcut. I know it doesn't make a negative value positive.`</EDIT>`

The [C# language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#unary-plus-and-minus-operators) doesn't say much about it:

> The unary + operator returns the value of its operand.

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727516/what-does-the-unary-plus-operator-do) on SO about this, but it is tagged with C, C++ and C#, and none of the answers clearly mentions C#.

Comment: What do you mean by “safe”? It exists, it does what it does, it wouldn’t exist if it was somehow dangerous or not-to-be-used. 

Also it does not emphasize the value being positive, the value can be negative also.

Comment: _"just to emphasize that the value is positive"_ - it doesn't do that: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tVbiaQ

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? C# is a completely different programming language, albeit C like.

Comment: As they would in a Mathematical formula, the operators act as "+1 * value" or "-1 * value". But that's regardless of whether the value is positive or negative. With + the sign does not change, with - the sign is flipped. (On the evaluated expression, not the value itself as shown in Peter's answer.)

Comment: On all .NET number types the unary +  is a no-op. You can however [overload this operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) for your own types.

Comment: _"You can however overload this operator for your own types."_ - which would be surprizing to the average developer, though :(

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?" Are you asking if it has the same "potentially dangerous" effects as in C++? If so, what are the "potentially dangerous" effects of unary `+` in C++? Please clarify.

Comment: I'm asking about the potentially dangerous effects, not how it affects the value. In c++, arithmetic promotion is performed, which for example may affect which function overload is choosed.

Comment: Why not test it quick if you want to be sure? https://dotnetfiddle.net/aS89qy

Comment: @Fildor I'm asking not only about changing the type. I want to know if it is considered a good and safe practise in general.

Comment: Practice for what? Indicating that the value is supposed to be positive? - Then no, it's not good for that.

Comment: No for that, for indicating that value is not opposite, to put the emphasis on the absence of unary - (minus)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/R6V0OU - look at this. Even in the case of intentional errors with overloading of the unary plus operator and implicit type conversion, there will be no problem. Plus applied to `doube`, not to `MyDouble`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903114/5133585) of the question you linked says, unary `+` in C(++) does *do something*, and is not necessarily a no-op. This is true in C# too.

C# only has these unary `+` operators (See [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1182-unary-plus-operator)):

```
int operator +(int x);
uint operator +(uint x);
long operator +(long x);
ulong operator +(ulong x);
float operator +(float x);
double operator +(double x);
decimal operator +(decimal x);
```

So if `x` is a `short`, `+x` would be of type `int`, because the first operator is selected by overload resolution. As a result, something like this does not compile:

```
short x = 1;
short y = +x;
```

This also affects overload resolution, among other things. Just like the code presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903114/5133585), if you do:

```
public class C {
    public static void Foo(int x) {
        Console.WriteLine("int");
    }
    
    public static void Foo(short x) {
        Console.WriteLine("short");
    }
}
```

`C.Foo(x)` where `x` is a `short` will print `short`, but `C.Foo(+x)` will print `int`.

Does this situations like the above happens often enough that makes `+x` a "bad" or "unsafe" practice? That is for you to decide.

Of course, if `x` is of a custom struct/class type, then `+x` could do basically anything. Unary `+` is overloadable.

Comment: Does that type changing behavior make it not recommended in C# community?

Comment: @michuu No, as far as I'm aware. There isn't many situations like `C.Foo`, where there is an `int` overload and a `short` overload that does completely different things. Overloads are supposed to do *similar* things after all. So even if you call the "wrong" one, it should still behave the same (with just an extra useless conversion). When the type actually matters, it is better to give the methods different names.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the accurate answer!

Answer (score 1):

`+` and `-` will not change the original double value if that's what you mean by safe.

```
double d = 7d;
Console.WriteLine(d);  //7
Console.WriteLine(+d); //7
Console.WriteLine(-d); //-7
Console.WriteLine(d);  //7

//OR
d = -7d;
Console.WriteLine(d);  //-7
Console.WriteLine(+d); //-7
Console.WriteLine(-d); //7
Console.WriteLine(d);  //-7
```

Comment: Does it change the value type in any way or is it always no-op?

Comment: @michuu No it does not change the value type. Even if you change the `double` to `uint` or `byte` the first part works well. The `d = -7` will cause compile time error.

Comment: @PeterCsala as Sweeper answer point out, this is not true, if the variable is a `short` or `byte` the unary will change it to `int`

Comment: @Magnetron Yepp, I saw it.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have provided a great explanation of what will go on with use of `+`.

Just wanted to flag that just like in C/C++ there also is the integral numeric types all have unsigned versions. Of course, both share the same [concerns](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/unsigned-integers-and-why-to-avoid-them/) of wrapping around when bad operations are done with them

The following code snippet is just a joke, don't kill me, but here is an extension method to check if a numeric type is positive without risk of altering the original's value or typing

```cs
public static class NumericExtensions<T> where T : struct
{
    public static bool IsPositive(this T num) =>
        num switch  
        {  
            num is uint _ => true,
            num is int i => i > 0,
            num is ulong _ => true,
            num is long l => l > 0,
            num is double d => d > 0,
            num is float f => f > 0,
            num is decimal m => m > 0m
            //... add remaining numeric types
            _ => false //or throw exception
        };
}
```