# C - redefinition error in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, header-files, redefinition

My c header file has the following error message in Xcode

```
Redefinition of 'entry'
```

But it works perfectly when I compile it using `gcc` in command line. Could any of you give an explanation of why?

This is `snapshot.h`:

```
#ifndef SNAPSHOT_H
#define SNAPSHOT_H

#define MAX_KEY_LENGTH 16
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1024

typedef struct value value;
typedef struct entry entry;
typedef struct snapshot snapshot;

struct value {
    value* prev;
    value* next;
    int value;
};

// the line below is where the redefinition error appears
struct entry {
    entry* prev;
    entry* next;
    value* values;
    char key[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
};

struct snapshot {
    snapshot* prev;
    snapshot* next;
    entry* entries;
    int id;
};

#endif
```

This is snapshot.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include "snapshot.h"

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int x = 7;
    printf("x= %d\n" , x);
    printf("value = %d\n", 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is that the *complete* error? Please edit your question to include the compete and unedited error output.

Comment: Yes. That was the complete error. @Benjy's answer has well solved that. Thanks for Paul's comment too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`entry` was originally reserved as a keyword and then later declared obsolete. So older compilers don't allow it (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254395/what-ever-happened-to-the-entry-keyword)). Change the name of the struct and everything should be fine.

Comment: Alternatively compiling with e.g. `-std=c99` may fix this.