# Has entry keyword ever been implemented in C?

Tags: c, keyword, language-design

`entry` is a reserved identifier in K&R1, which seems to come from [PL/I](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/enterprise-developer/ed90/ED-Eclipse/BKPFPFSTMTENTRY.html) and [FORTRAN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn99/index.html).
Someone already posted a question about `entry` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254395/whatever-happened-to-the-entry-keyword), and the accepted answer said some compilers implemented it, but the K&R2 states

> entry, formerly reserved but never used, is no longer reserved

Who is right ? Did the K&R2 take a shortcut because it was almost not used, and maybe it wasn't relevant for the reader ? Then, if `entry` has existed, which compilers did implement it ?

In their answer, the author also shared this [link](http://bytes.com/forum/thread214853.html), but it only suggests some compilers implemented it, without giving any example though :

> Some C compilers prior to the standard implemented that keyword.
> Since it was never part of any version of the C standard, it has no
> defined standardized meaning.

I asked this question by curiosity, as I'm very interested about early C.

Comment: *entry, formerly reserved but **never used*** How have you come to the question *which compilers did implement it*?

Comment: As I explained, I asked because an accepted answer said so, and posted a link where someone also states some compilers used it. I thought reasonable not to talk much about entry in K&R2 if this keyword was implemented by a few compilers.

Here's the quote from the bytes.com link :

Some C compilers prior to the standard implemented that keyword.
Since it was never part of any version of the C standard, it has no
defined standardized meaning.

Comment: You may also try [retrocomputing.se].

Comment: I wonder if rather it was simply _reserved_ by implementations (so they recognised it as a keyword and not a symbol) rather than actually used for anything, and the author has conflated that with implementation?

Comment: I think from the standpoint of the K&R authors it was never used. That is, THEY never described it as being used for anything. At that point (pre ANSI C)  the "C standard" was what they had written. And then the ANSI folks removed it.

Comment: Fortran was very popular at that time and they simply borrowed it from there. Thanks God this weird idea died :)

Comment: IMHO the inventors of C should have a heavy weight deciding if it is no longer reserved, but today that subject should be checked against the standard.  Are you interested in the fashion interest this can trigger or you need it for something.  What is the interest of checking which compilers do implement it?  Do you know what it was for?